# Interpolation on large 2D list results in erratic function

Tags: plotting, interpolation

Previously, I've had problems with *Mathematica* interpolating and plotting 3D lists, but I finally managed to do so by rescaling the x and y-axes with the help of the methods proposed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19253/plotting-a-3d-list-causes-kernel-to-crash-if-x-and-y-axes-have-vastly-different). Now my problem is with interpolating 2D lists.

I have a large 2D list that I'll call `data` of dimensions {4271,2} for which I need to find an interpolation.  Using `f = Interpolation[data]` outputs an interpolating function without error messages or warnings. The problem arises first when comparing the curves produced by `ListLinePlot[data]` and `Plot[f[s], {s, Min[data[[All, 1]]], Max[data[[All, 1]]]}]` as shown below. The first plot looks like this:

[image]

and the second like this:

[image]

The first plot produces the expected curve whilst the second shows erratic behaviour between points. Evaluating the interpolating function offers only sensible result at points present in `data` and incoherent results elsewhere. I've tried sorting, cleaning, introducing noise into the data, but the interpolation always produces an erratic function.

I'll post an excerpt of the first 900 rows of the data below. Any help is much appreciated.

```
data[[1 ;; 900, All]] = {{1779.55, 9.9227*10^6}, {1784.38, 9.9225*10^6}, {1789.02, 
  9.92229*10^6}, {1793.49, 9.92208*10^6}, {1797.79, 
  9.92187*10^6}, {1808.57, 9.92165*10^6}, {1819.04, 
  9.92143*10^6}, {1829.07, 9.9212*10^6}, {1838.74, 
  9.92097*10^6}, {1848.07, 9.92074*10^6}, {1857.03, 
  9.9205*10^6}, {1865.69, 9.92026*10^6}, {1872.35, 
  9.92001*10^6}, {1875.87, 9.91976*10^6}, {1879.27, 
  9.91951*10^6}, {1882.56, 9.91925*10^6}, {1885.76, 
  9.91899*10^6}, {1888.86, 9.91872*10^6}, {1891.86, 
  9.91845*10^6}, {1896.6, 9.91818*10^6}, {1903.59, 
  9.9179*10^6}, {1910.38, 9.91762*10^6}, {1916.98, 
  9.91733*10^6}, {1923.36, 9.91704*10^6}, {1929.56, 
  9.91675*10^6}, {1935.6, 9.91645*10^6}, {1941.47, 
  9.91615*10^6}, {1947.16, 9.91584*10^6}, {1952.68, 
  9.91553*10^6}, {1958.05, 9.91522*10^6}, {1963.29, 
  9.9149*10^6}, {1968.4, 9.91458*10^6}, {1971.81, 
  9.91425*10^6}, {1974.01, 9.91392*10^6}, {1976.16, 
  9.91359*10^6}, {1978.26, 9.91325*10^6}, {1980.3, 
  9.91291*10^6}, {1982.3, 9.91256*10^6}, {1984.25, 
  9.91221*10^6}, {1986.15, 9.91186*10^6}, {1990.17, 
  9.9115*10^6}, {1994.44, 9.91114*10^6}, {1998.61, 
  9.91077*10^6}, {2002.69, 9.9104*10^6}, {2006.68, 
  9.91003*10^6}, {2010.59, 9.90965*10^6}, {2014.39, 
  9.90927*10^6}, {2018.11, 9.90888*10^6}, {2021.75, 
  9.90849*10^6}, {2025.31, 9.9081*10^6}, {2028.8, 
  9.9077*10^6}, {2032.23, 9.9073*10^6}, {2035.58, 
  9.90689*10^6}, {2038.86, 9.90648*10^6}, {2040.37, 
  9.90607*10^6}, {2041.84, 9.90565*10^6}, {2043.29, 
  9.90523*10^6}, {2044.7, 9.9048*10^6}, {2046.09, 
  9.90437*10^6}, {2047.45, 9.90394*10^6}, {2048.79, 
  9.9035*10^6}, {2050.1, 9.90306*10^6}, {2052.63, 
  9.90261*10^6}, {2055.48, 9.90216*10^6}, {2058.28, 
  9.90171*10^6}, {2061.03, 9.90125*10^6}, {2063.73, 
  9.90079*10^6}, {2066.38, 9.90032*10^6}, {2068.99, 
  9.89985*10^6}, {2071.56, 9.89938*10^6}, {2074.08, 
  9.8989*10^6}, {2076.55, 9.89842*10^6}, {2078.97, 
  9.89793*10^6}, {2081.35, 9.89744*10^6}, {2083.68, 
  9.89695*10^6}, {2085.98, 9.89645*10^6}, {2088.25, 
  9.89595*10^6}, {2090.47, 9.89544*10^6}, {2092.66, 
  9.89493*10^6}, {2094.82, 9.89442*10^6}, {2096.94, 
  9.8939*10^6}, {2099.03, 9.89338*10^6}, {2101.08, 
  9.89285*10^6}, {2102.83, 9.89232*10^6}, {2103.77, 
  9.89179*10^6}, {2104.7, 9.89125*10^6}, {2105.62, 
  9.89071*10^6}, {2106.52, 9.89016*10^6}, {2107.41, 
  9.88961*10^6}, {2108.28, 9.88906*10^6}, {2109.14, 
  9.8885*10^6}, {2109.98, 9.88794*10^6}, {2111.38, 
  9.88737*10^6}, {2113.19, 9.8868*10^6}, {2114.98, 
  9.88623*10^6}, {2116.74, 9.88565*10^6}, {2118.47, 
  9.88507*10^6}, {2120.19, 9.88448*10^6}, {2121.87, 
  9.88389*10^6}, {2123.54, 9.8833*10^6}, {2125.18, 
  9.8827*10^6}, {2126.8, 9.8821*10^6}, {2128.39, 
  9.88149*10^6}, {2129.97, 9.88088*10^6}, {2131.52, 
  9.88027*10^6}, {2133.05, 9.87965*10^6}, {2134.56, 
  9.87903*10^6}, {2136.05, 9.8784*10^6}, {2137.5, 
  9.87777*10^6}, {2138.94, 9.87714*10^6}, {2140.36, 
  9.8765*10^6}, {2141.76, 9.87586*10^6}, {2143.14, 
  9.87521*10^6}, {2144.5, 9.87456*10^6}, {2145.84, 
  9.87391*10^6}, {2147.17, 9.87325*10^6}, {2148.48, 
  9.87259*10^6}, {2149.78, 9.87192*10^6}, {2151.06, 
  9.87125*10^6}, {2152.32, 9.87058*10^6}, {2153.56, 
  9.8699*10^6}, {2154.79, 9.86922*10^6}, {2156.01, 
  9.86853*10^6}, {2157.21, 9.86784*10^6}, {2158.39, 
  9.86715*10^6}, {2159.57, 9.86645*10^6}, {2160.72, 
  9.86575*10^6}, {2161.33, 9.86504*10^6}, {2161.86, 
  9.86433*10^6}, {2162.38, 9.86362*10^6}, {2162.9, 
  9.8629*10^6}, {2163.41, 9.86218*10^6}, {2163.91, 
  9.86145*10^6}, {2164.4, 9.86072*10^6}, {2164.89, 
  9.85999*10^6}, {2165.39, 9.85925*10^6}, {2166.46, 
  9.85851*10^6}, {2167.51, 9.85776*10^6}, {2168.55, 
  9.85701*10^6}, {2169.58, 9.85626*10^6}, {2170.6, 
  9.8555*10^6}, {2171.6, 9.85474*10^6}, {2172.6, 
  9.85397*10^6}, {2173.58, 9.8532*10^6}, {2174.55, 
  9.85243*10^6}, {2175.52, 9.85165*10^6}, {2176.47, 
  9.85087*10^6}, {2177.41, 9.85008*10^6}, {2178.34, 
  9.84929*10^6}, {2179.26, 9.8485*10^6}, {2180.16, 
  9.8477*10^6}, {2181.06, 9.8469*10^6}, {2181.95, 
  9.84609*10^6}, {2182.83, 9.84528*10^6}, {2183.7, 
  9.84447*10^6}, {2184.56, 9.84365*10^6}, {2185.41, 
  9.84283*10^6}, {2186.26, 9.842*10^6}, {2187.09, 
  9.84117*10^6}, {2187.91, 9.84034*10^6}, {2188.73, 
  9.8395*10^6}, {2189.53, 9.83866*10^6}, {2190.32, 
  9.83781*10^6}, {2191.11, 9.83696*10^6}, {2191.88, 
  9.83611*10^6}, {2192.65, 9.83525*10^6}, {2193.41, 
  9.83439*10^6}, {2194.16, 9.83352*10^6}, {2194.91, 
  9.83265*10^6}, {2195.64, 9.83178*10^6}, {2196.37, 
  9.8309*10^6}, {2197.09, 9.83002*10^6}, {2197.8, 
  9.82913*10^6}, {2198.51, 9.82824*10^6}, {2199.21, 
  9.82735*10^6}, {2199.9, 9.82645*10^6}, {2200.58, 
  9.82555*10^6}, {2201.26, 9.82464*10^6}, {2201.93, 
  9.82373*10^6}, {2202.6, 9.82282*10^6}, {2203.25, 
  9.8219*10^6}, {2203.9, 9.82098*10^6}, {2204.55, 
  9.82005*10^6}, {2205.18, 9.81912*10^6}, {2205.82, 
  9.81819*10^6}, {2206.44, 9.81725*10^6}, {2207.06, 
  9.81631*10^6}, {2207.67, 9.81536*10^6}, {2208.28, 
  9.81441*10^6}, {2208.88, 9.81346*10^6}, {2209.47, 
  9.8125*10^6}, {2210.06, 9.81154*10^6}, {2210.64, 
  9.81057*10^6}, {2211.22, 9.8096*10^6}, {2211.6, 
  9.80863*10^6}, {2211.83, 9.80765*10^6}, {2212.05, 
  9.80667*10^6}, {2212.28, 9.80568*10^6}, {2212.5, 
  9.80469*10^6}, {2212.71, 9.8037*10^6}, {2212.93, 
  9.8027*10^6}, {2213.14, 9.8017*10^6}, {2213.61, 
  9.80069*10^6}, {2214.15, 9.79968*10^6}, {2214.69, 
  9.79867*10^6}, {2215.22, 9.79765*10^6}, {2215.74, 
  9.79663*10^6}, {2216.26, 9.7956*10^6}, {2216.77, 
  9.79457*10^6}, {2217.28, 9.79354*10^6}, {2217.78, 
  9.7925*10^6}, {2218.28, 9.79146*10^6}, {2218.78, 
  9.79041*10^6}, {2219.27, 9.78936*10^6}, {2219.75, 
  9.78831*10^6}, {2220.23, 9.78725*10^6}, {2220.71, 
  9.78619*10^6}, {2221.18, 9.78512*10^6}, {2221.64, 
  9.78405*10^6}, {2222.1, 9.78298*10^6}, {2222.56, 
  9.7819*10^6}, {2223.02, 9.78082*10^6}, {2223.46, 
  9.77973*10^6}, {2223.91, 9.77864*10^6}, {2224.35, 
  9.77755*10^6}, {2224.79, 9.77645*10^6}, {2225.22, 
  9.77535*10^6}, {2225.65, 9.77424*10^6}, {2226.07, 
  9.77313*10^6}, {2226.49, 9.77202*10^6}, {2226.91, 
  9.7709*10^6}, {2227.32, 9.76978*10^6}, {2227.73, 
  9.76865*10^6}, {2228.13, 9.76752*10^6}, {2228.53, 
  9.76639*10^6}, {2228.93, 9.76525*10^6}, {2229.32, 
  9.76411*10^6}, {2229.71, 9.76296*10^6}, {2230.1, 
  9.76181*10^6}, {2230.48, 9.76066*10^6}, {2230.86, 
  9.7595*10^6}, {2231.23, 9.75834*10^6}, {2231.6, 
  9.75717*10^6}, {2231.97, 9.756*10^6}, {2232.34, 
  9.75483*10^6}, {2232.69, 9.75365*10^6}, {2233.05, 
  9.75247*10^6}, {2233.4, 9.75128*10^6}, {2233.74, 
  9.75009*10^6}, {2234.09, 9.7489*10^6}, {2234.43, 
  9.7477*10^6}, {2234.77, 9.7465*10^6}, {2235.1, 
  9.74529*10^6}, {2235.43, 9.74408*10^6}, {2235.76, 
  9.74287*10^6}, {2236.08, 9.74165*10^6}, {2236.41, 
  9.74043*10^6}, {2236.72, 9.7392*10^6}, {2237.04, 
  9.73797*10^6}, {2237.35, 9.73674*10^6}, {2237.66, 
  9.7355*10^6}, {2237.97, 9.73426*10^6}, {2238.27, 
  9.73301*10^6}, {2238.57, 9.73176*10^6}, {2238.87, 
  9.73051*10^6}, {2239.17, 9.72925*10^6}, {2239.46, 
  9.72799*10^6}, {2239.75, 9.72672*10^6}, {2240.03, 
  9.72545*10^6}, {2240.32, 9.72418*10^6}, {2240.6, 
  9.7229*10^6}, {2240.88, 9.72162*10^6}, {2241.15, 
  9.72033*10^6}, {2241.43, 9.71904*10^6}, {2241.7, 
  9.71775*10^6}, {2241.96, 9.71645*10^6}, {2242.23, 
  9.71515*10^6}, {2242.49, 9.71384*10^6}, {2242.75, 
  9.71253*10^6}, {2243.01, 9.71122*10^6}, {2243.26, 
  9.7099*10^6}, {2243.51, 9.70858*10^6}, {2243.76, 
  9.70725*10^6}, {2244.01, 9.70592*10^6}, {2244.26, 
  9.70459*10^6}, {2244.5, 9.70325*10^6}, {2244.74, 
  9.70191*10^6}, {2244.98, 9.70056*10^6}, {2245.21, 
  9.69921*10^6}, {2245.44, 9.69786*10^6}, {2245.67, 
  9.6965*10^6}, {2245.9, 9.69514*10^6}, {2246.13, 
  9.69377*10^6}, {2246.35, 9.6924*10^6}, {2246.57, 
  9.69103*10^6}, {2246.79, 9.68965*10^6}, {2247.01, 
  9.68827*10^6}, {2247.22, 9.68688*10^6}, {2247.44, 
  9.68549*10^6}, {2247.65, 9.6841*10^6}, {2247.76, 
  9.6827*10^6}, {2247.78, 9.6813*10^6}, {2247.79, 
  9.67989*10^6}, {2247.8, 9.67848*10^6}, {2247.95, 
  9.67707*10^6}, {2248.16, 9.67565*10^6}, {2248.36, 
  9.67423*10^6}, {2248.56, 9.6728*10^6}, {2248.76, 
  9.67137*10^6}, {2248.96, 9.66994*10^6}, {2249.15, 
  9.6685*10^6}, {2249.34, 9.66706*10^6}, {2249.53, 
  9.66561*10^6}, {2249.72, 9.66416*10^6}, {2249.91, 
  9.66271*10^6}, {2250.09, 9.66125*10^6}, {2250.27, 
  9.65979*10^6}, {2250.45, 9.65832*10^6}, {2250.63, 
  9.65685*10^6}, {2250.81, 9.65538*10^6}, {2250.98, 
  9.6539*10^6}, {2251.16, 9.65242*10^6}, {2251.33, 
  9.65093*10^6}, {2251.5, 9.64944*10^6}, {2251.66, 
  9.64795*10^6}, {2251.83, 9.64645*10^6}, {2251.99, 
  9.64495*10^6}, {2252.15, 9.64344*10^6}, {2252.31, 
  9.64193*10^6}, {2252.47, 9.64042*10^6}, {2252.62, 
  9.6389*10^6}, {2252.78, 9.63738*10^6}, {2252.93, 
  9.63585*10^6}, {2253.08, 9.63432*10^6}, {2253.23, 
  9.63279*10^6}, {2253.38, 9.63125*10^6}, {2253.52, 
  9.62971*10^6}, {2253.67, 9.62816*10^6}, {2253.81, 
  9.62661*10^6}, {2253.95, 9.62506*10^6}, {2254.09, 
  9.6235*10^6}, {2254.22, 9.62194*10^6}, {2254.36, 
  9.62037*10^6}, {2254.49, 9.6188*10^6}, {2254.62, 
  9.61723*10^6}, {2254.75, 9.61565*10^6}, {2254.88, 
  9.61407*10^6}, {2255.01, 9.61248*10^6}, {2255.13, 
  9.61089*10^6}, {2255.26, 9.6093*10^6}, {2255.38, 
  9.6077*10^6}, {2255.5, 9.6061*10^6}, {2255.62, 
  9.60449*10^6}, {2255.74, 9.60288*10^6}, {2255.85, 
  9.60127*10^6}, {2255.97, 9.59965*10^6}, {2256.08, 
  9.59803*10^6}, {2256.19, 9.5964*10^6}, {2256.3, 
  9.59477*10^6}, {2256.41, 9.59314*10^6}, {2256.51, 
  9.5915*10^6}, {2256.62, 9.58986*10^6}, {2256.72, 
  9.58821*10^6}, {2256.82, 9.58656*10^6}, {2256.92, 
  9.58491*10^6}, {2257.02, 9.58325*10^6}, {2257.12, 
  9.58159*10^6}, {2257.22, 9.57992*10^6}, {2257.31, 
  9.57825*10^6}, {2257.4, 9.57658*10^6}, {2257.5, 
  9.5749*10^6}, {2257.58, 9.57322*10^6}, {2257.67, 
  9.57153*10^6}, {2257.75, 9.56984*10^6}, {2257.84, 
  9.56815*10^6}, {2257.92, 9.56645*10^6}, {2258., 
  9.56475*10^6}, {2258.08, 9.56304*10^6}, {2258.16, 
  9.56133*10^6}, {2258.23, 9.55962*10^6}, {2258.39, 
  9.5579*10^6}, {2258.82, 9.55618*10^6}, {2259.26, 
  9.55445*10^6}, {2259.69, 9.55272*10^6}, {2260.13, 
  9.55099*10^6}, {2260.55, 9.54925*10^6}, {2260.98, 
  9.54751*10^6}, {2261.4, 9.54576*10^6}, {2261.82, 
  9.54401*10^6}, {2262.24, 9.54226*10^6}, {2262.65, 
  9.5405*10^6}, {2263.06, 9.53874*10^6}, {2263.47, 
  9.53697*10^6}, {2263.87, 9.5352*10^6}, {2264.28, 
  9.53343*10^6}, {2264.68, 9.53165*10^6}, {2265.07, 
  9.52987*10^6}, {2265.47, 9.52808*10^6}, {2265.86, 
  9.52629*10^6}, {2266.25, 9.5245*10^6}, {2266.63, 
  9.5227*10^6}, {2267.02, 9.5209*10^6}, {2267.4, 
  9.51909*10^6}, {2267.78, 9.51728*10^6}, {2268.17, 
  9.51547*10^6}, {2268.56, 9.51365*10^6}, {2268.94, 
  9.51183*10^6}, {2269.33, 9.51*10^6}, {2269.71, 
  9.50817*10^6}, {2270.09, 9.50634*10^6}, {2270.47, 
  9.5045*10^6}, {2270.84, 9.50266*10^6}, {2271.21, 
  9.50081*10^6}, {2271.58, 9.49896*10^6}, {2271.95, 
  9.49711*10^6}, {2272.31, 9.49525*10^6}, {2272.67, 
  9.49339*10^6}, {2273.03, 9.49152*10^6}, {2273.39, 
  9.48965*10^6}, {2273.74, 9.48778*10^6}, {2274.09, 
  9.4859*10^6}, {2274.44, 9.48402*10^6}, {2274.78, 
  9.48213*10^6}, {2275.13, 9.48024*10^6}, {2275.47, 
  9.47835*10^6}, {2275.81, 9.47645*10^6}, {2276.14, 
  9.47455*10^6}, {2276.48, 9.47264*10^6}, {2276.81, 
  9.47073*10^6}, {2277.14, 9.46882*10^6}, {2277.5, 
  9.4669*10^6}, {2277.93, 9.46498*10^6}, {2278.35, 
  9.46305*10^6}, {2278.77, 9.46112*10^6}, {2279.19, 
  9.45919*10^6}, {2279.61, 9.45725*10^6}, {2280.02, 
  9.45531*10^6}, {2280.4, 9.45336*10^6}, {2280.75, 
  9.45141*10^6}, {2281.1, 9.44946*10^6}, {2281.44, 
  9.4475*10^6}, {2281.79, 9.44554*10^6}, {2282.13, 
  9.44357*10^6}, {2282.47, 9.4416*10^6}, {2282.81, 
  9.43963*10^6}, {2283.14, 9.43765*10^6}, {2283.47, 
  9.43567*10^6}, {2283.8, 9.43368*10^6}, {2284.13, 
  9.43169*10^6}, {2284.46, 9.4297*10^6}, {2284.78, 
  9.4277*10^6}, {2285.1, 9.4257*10^6}, {2285.42, 
  9.42369*10^6}, {2285.73, 9.42168*10^6}, {2286.05, 
  9.41967*10^6}, {2286.36, 9.41765*10^6}, {2286.67, 
  9.41563*10^6}, {2286.97, 9.4136*10^6}, {2287.28, 
  9.41157*10^6}, {2287.58, 9.40954*10^6}, {2287.88, 
  9.4075*10^6}, {2288.18, 9.40546*10^6}, {2288.47, 
  9.40341*10^6}, {2288.77, 9.40136*10^6}, {2289.06, 
  9.39931*10^6}, {2289.35, 9.39725*10^6}, {2289.63, 
  9.39519*10^6}, {2289.92, 9.39312*10^6}, {2290.2, 
  9.39105*10^6}, {2290.48, 9.38898*10^6}, {2290.76, 
  9.3869*10^6}, {2291.04, 9.38482*10^6}, {2291.31, 
  9.38273*10^6}, {2291.58, 9.38064*10^6}, {2291.85, 
  9.37855*10^6}, {2292.12, 9.37645*10^6}, {2292.39, 
  9.37435*10^6}, {2292.65, 9.37224*10^6}, {2292.91, 
  9.37013*10^6}, {2293.17, 9.36802*10^6}, {2293.43, 
  9.3659*10^6}, {2293.68, 9.36378*10^6}, {2293.94, 
  9.36165*10^6}, {2294.19, 9.35952*10^6}, {2294.44, 
  9.35739*10^6}, {2294.69, 9.35525*10^6}, {2294.93, 
  9.35311*10^6}, {2295.18, 9.35096*10^6}, {2295.42, 
  9.34881*10^6}, {2295.66, 9.34666*10^6}, {2295.9, 
  9.3445*10^6}, {2296.23, 9.34234*10^6}, {2296.6, 
  9.34017*10^6}, {2296.96, 9.338*10^6}, {2297.32, 
  9.33583*10^6}, {2297.68, 9.33365*10^6}, {2298.03, 
  9.33147*10^6}, {2298.39, 9.32928*10^6}, {2298.74, 
  9.32709*10^6}, {2299.09, 9.3249*10^6}, {2299.39, 
  9.3227*10^6}, {2299.65, 9.3205*10^6}, {2299.9, 
  9.31829*10^6}, {2300.15, 9.31608*10^6}, {2300.4, 
  9.31387*10^6}, {2300.65, 9.31165*10^6}, {2300.9, 
  9.30943*10^6}, {2301.14, 9.3072*10^6}, {2301.38, 
  9.30497*10^6}, {2301.62, 9.30274*10^6}, {2301.86, 
  9.3005*10^6}, {2302.1, 9.29826*10^6}, {2302.33, 
  9.29601*10^6}, {2302.56, 9.29376*10^6}, {2302.8, 
  9.29151*10^6}, {2303.02, 9.28925*10^6}, {2303.25, 
  9.28699*10^6}, {2303.48, 9.28472*10^6}, {2303.7, 
  9.28245*10^6}, {2303.92, 9.28018*10^6}, {2304.14, 
  9.2779*10^6}, {2304.36, 9.27562*10^6}, {2304.57, 
  9.27333*10^6}, {2304.79, 9.27104*10^6}, {2305., 
  9.26875*10^6}, {2305.21, 9.26645*10^6}, {2305.42, 
  9.26415*10^6}, {2305.62, 9.26184*10^6}, {2305.83, 
  9.25953*10^6}, {2306.03, 9.25722*10^6}, {2306.23, 
  9.2549*10^6}, {2306.43, 9.25258*10^6}, {2306.63, 
  9.25025*10^6}, {2306.83, 9.24792*10^6}, {2307.02, 
  9.24559*10^6}, {2307.21, 9.24325*10^6}, {2307.4, 
  9.24091*10^6}, {2307.59, 9.23856*10^6}, {2307.78, 
  9.23621*10^6}, {2307.96, 9.23386*10^6}, {2308.15, 
  9.2315*10^6}, {2308.33, 9.22914*10^6}, {2308.51, 
  9.22677*10^6}, {2308.69, 9.2244*10^6}, {2308.87, 
  9.22203*10^6}, {2309.04, 9.21965*10^6}, {2309.22, 
  9.21727*10^6}, {2309.39, 9.21488*10^6}, {2309.56, 
  9.21249*10^6}, {2309.73, 9.2101*10^6}, {2309.89, 
  9.2077*10^6}, {2310.06, 9.2053*10^6}, {2310.22, 
  9.20289*10^6}, {2310.38, 9.20048*10^6}, {2310.69, 
  9.19807*10^6}, {2311.04, 9.19565*10^6}, {2311.38, 
  9.19323*10^6}, {2311.63, 9.1908*10^6}, {2311.82, 
  9.18837*10^6}, {2312.01, 9.18594*10^6}, {2312.19, 
  9.1835*10^6}, {2312.38, 9.18106*10^6}, {2312.56, 
  9.17861*10^6}, {2312.74, 9.17616*10^6}, {2312.92, 
  9.17371*10^6}, {2313.1, 9.17125*10^6}, {2313.28, 
  9.16879*10^6}, {2313.45, 9.16632*10^6}, {2313.62, 
  9.16385*10^6}, {2313.79, 9.16138*10^6}, {2313.96, 
  9.1589*10^6}, {2314.13, 9.15642*10^6}, {2314.3, 
  9.15393*10^6}, {2314.46, 9.15144*10^6}, {2314.63, 
  9.14895*10^6}, {2314.84, 9.14645*10^6}, {2315.05, 
  9.14395*10^6}, {2315.25, 9.14144*10^6}, {2315.46, 
  9.13893*10^6}, {2315.66, 9.13642*10^6}, {2315.87, 
  9.1339*10^6}, {2316.07, 9.13138*10^6}, {2316.27, 
  9.12885*10^6}, {2316.47, 9.12632*10^6}, {2316.66, 
  9.12379*10^6}, {2316.86, 9.12125*10^6}, {2317.05, 
  9.11871*10^6}, {2317.25, 9.11616*10^6}, {2317.44, 
  9.11361*10^6}, {2317.63, 9.11106*10^6}, {2317.82, 
  9.1085*10^6}, {2318.01, 9.10594*10^6}, {2318.19, 
  9.10337*10^6}, {2318.38, 9.1008*10^6}, {2318.56, 
  9.09823*10^6}, {2318.74, 9.09565*10^6}, {2318.92, 
  9.09307*10^6}, {2319.1, 9.09048*10^6}, {2319.28, 
  9.08789*10^6}, {2319.46, 9.0853*10^6}, {2319.63, 
  9.0827*10^6}, {2319.81, 9.0801*10^6}, {2319.98, 
  9.07749*10^6}, {2320.15, 9.07488*10^6}, {2320.32, 
  9.07227*10^6}, {2320.49, 9.06965*10^6}, {2320.59, 
  9.06703*10^6}, {2320.67, 9.0644*10^6}, {2320.74, 
  9.06177*10^6}, {2320.81, 9.05914*10^6}, {2320.88, 
  9.0565*10^6}, {2320.95, 9.05386*10^6}, {2321.01, 
  9.05121*10^6}, {2321.08, 9.04856*10^6}, {2321.14, 
  9.04591*10^6}, {2321.21, 9.04325*10^6}, {2321.27, 
  9.04059*10^6}, {2321.48, 9.03792*10^6}, {2321.71, 
  9.03525*10^6}, {2321.94, 9.03258*10^6}, {2322.17, 
  9.0299*10^6}, {2322.4, 9.02722*10^6}, {2322.63, 
  9.02453*10^6}, {2322.86, 9.02184*10^6}, {2323.08, 
  9.01915*10^6}, {2323.31, 9.01645*10^6}, {2323.53, 
  9.01375*10^6}, {2323.75, 9.01104*10^6}, {2323.97, 
  9.00833*10^6}, {2324.19, 9.00562*10^6}, {2324.41, 
  9.0029*10^6}, {2324.62, 9.00018*10^6}, {2324.84, 
  8.99745*10^6}, {2325.05, 8.99472*10^6}, {2325.27, 
  8.99199*10^6}, {2325.48, 8.98925*10^6}, {2325.69, 
  8.98651*10^6}, {2325.89, 8.98376*10^6}, {2326.1, 
  8.98101*10^6}, {2326.31, 8.97826*10^6}, {2326.51, 
  8.9755*10^6}, {2326.72, 8.97274*10^6}, {2326.92, 
  8.96997*10^6}, {2327.12, 8.9672*10^6}, {2327.32, 
  8.96443*10^6}, {2327.52, 8.96165*10^6}, {2327.71, 
  8.95887*10^6}, {2327.91, 8.95608*10^6}, {2328.08, 
  8.95329*10^6}, {2328.12, 8.9505*10^6}, {2328.16, 
  8.9477*10^6}, {2328.2, 8.9449*10^6}, {2328.24, 
  8.94209*10^6}, {2328.28, 8.93928*10^6}, {2328.32, 
  8.93647*10^6}, {2328.35, 8.93365*10^6}, {2328.38, 
  8.93083*10^6}, {2328.42, 8.928*10^6}, {2328.45, 
  8.92517*10^6}, {2328.48, 8.92234*10^6}, {2328.51, 
  8.9195*10^6}, {2328.53, 8.91666*10^6}, {2328.56, 
  8.91381*10^6}, {2328.58, 8.91096*10^6}, {2328.61, 
  8.90811*10^6}, {2328.63, 8.90525*10^6}, {2328.65, 
  8.90239*10^6}, {2328.67, 8.89952*10^6}, {2328.69, 
  8.89665*10^6}, {2328.71, 8.89378*10^6}, {2328.72, 
  8.8909*10^6}, {2328.74, 8.88802*10^6}, {2328.75, 
  8.88513*10^6}, {2328.77, 8.88224*10^6}, {2328.78, 
  8.87935*10^6}, {2328.79, 8.87645*10^6}, {2328.8, 
  8.87355*10^6}, {2328.8, 8.87064*10^6}, {2328.81, 
  8.86773*10^6}, {2328.86, 8.86482*10^6}, {2328.94, 
  8.8619*10^6}, {2329.03, 8.85898*10^6}, {2329.11, 
  8.85605*10^6}, {2329.19, 8.85312*10^6}, {2329.27, 
  8.85019*10^6}, {2329.35, 8.84725*10^6}, {2329.43, 
  8.84431*10^6}, {2329.51, 8.84136*10^6}, {2329.59, 
  8.83841*10^6}, {2329.66, 8.83546*10^6}, {2329.73, 
  8.8325*10^6}, {2329.81, 8.82954*10^6}, {2329.88, 
  8.82657*10^6}, {2329.95, 8.8236*10^6}, {2330.02, 
  8.82063*10^6}, {2330.09, 8.81765*10^6}, {2330.15, 
  8.81467*10^6}, {2330.22, 8.81168*10^6}, {2330.28, 
  8.80869*10^6}, {2330.35, 8.8057*10^6}, {2330.41, 
  8.8027*10^6}, {2330.47, 8.7997*10^6}, {2330.53, 
  8.79669*10^6}, {2330.59, 8.79368*10^6}, {2330.64, 
  8.79067*10^6}, {2330.7, 8.78765*10^6}, {2330.76, 
  8.78463*10^6}, {2330.81, 8.7816*10^6}, {2330.86, 
  8.77857*10^6}, {2330.92, 8.77554*10^6}, {2330.97, 
  8.7725*10^6}, {2331.02, 8.76946*10^6}, {2331.07, 
  8.76641*10^6}, {2331.11, 8.76336*10^6}, {2331.16, 
  8.76031*10^6}, {2331.21, 8.75725*10^6}, {2331.25, 
  8.75419*10^6}, {2331.29, 8.75112*10^6}, {2331.33, 
  8.74805*10^6}, {2331.38, 8.74498*10^6}, {2331.42, 
  8.7419*10^6}, {2331.45, 8.73882*10^6}, {2331.49, 
  8.73573*10^6}, {2331.53, 8.73264*10^6}, {2331.56, 
  8.72955*10^6}, {2331.6, 8.72645*10^6}, {2331.63, 
  8.72335*10^6}, {2331.67, 8.72024*10^6}, {2331.7, 
  8.71713*10^6}, {2331.73, 8.71402*10^6}, {2331.76, 
  8.7109*10^6}, {2331.78, 8.70778*10^6}, {2331.86, 
  8.70465*10^6}, {2331.96, 8.70152*10^6}, {2332.05, 
  8.69839*10^6}, {2332.15, 8.69525*10^6}, {2332.24, 
  8.69211*10^6}, {2332.34, 8.68896*10^6}, {2332.39, 
  8.68581*10^6}, {2332.32, 8.68266*10^6}, {2332.25, 
  8.6795*10^6}, {2332.18, 8.67634*10^6}, {2332.11, 
  8.67317*10^6}, {2332.11, 8.67*10^6}, {2332.12, 
  8.66683*10^6}, {2332.12, 8.66365*10^6}, {2332.13, 
  8.66047*10^6}, {2332.13, 8.65728*10^6}, {2332.14, 
  8.65409*10^6}, {2332.14, 8.6509*10^6}, {2332.14, 
  8.6477*10^6}, {2332.14, 8.6445*10^6}, {2332.14, 
  8.64129*10^6}, {2332.14, 8.63808*10^6}, {2332.14, 
  8.63487*10^6}, {2332.15, 8.63165*10^6}, {2332.21, 
  8.62843*10^6}, {2332.26, 8.6252*10^6}, {2332.32, 
  8.62197*10^6}, {2332.37, 8.61874*10^6}, {2332.42, 
  8.6155*10^6}, {2332.48, 8.61226*10^6}, {2332.53, 
  8.60901*10^6}, {2332.58, 8.60576*10^6}, {2332.62, 
  8.60251*10^6}, {2332.67, 8.59925*10^6}, {2332.72, 
  8.59599*10^6}, {2332.76, 8.59272*10^6}, {2332.81, 
  8.58945*10^6}, {2332.85, 8.58618*10^6}, {2332.89, 
  8.5829*10^6}, {2332.93, 8.57962*10^6}, {2332.97, 
  8.57633*10^6}, {2333.01, 8.57304*10^6}, {2333.05, 
  8.56975*10^6}, {2333.09, 8.56645*10^6}, {2333.12, 
  8.56315*10^6}, {2333.16, 8.55984*10^6}, {2333.19, 
  8.55653*10^6}, {2333.22, 8.55322*10^6}, {2333.25, 
  8.5499*10^6}, {2333.28, 8.54658*10^6}, {2333.31, 
  8.54325*10^6}, {2333.34, 8.53992*10^6}, {2333.37, 
  8.53659*10^6}, {2333.4, 8.53325*10^6}, {2333.42, 
  8.52991*10^6}, {2333.45, 8.52656*10^6}, {2333.47, 
  8.52321*10^6}, {2333.49, 8.51986*10^6}, {2333.51, 
  8.5165*10^6}, {2333.53, 8.51314*10^6}, {2333.55, 
  8.50977*10^6}, {2333.57, 8.5064*10^6}, {2333.59, 
  8.50303*10^6}, {2333.6, 8.49965*10^6}, {2333.62, 
  8.49627*10^6}, {2333.63, 8.49288*10^6}, {2333.65, 
  8.48949*10^6}, {2333.66, 8.4861*10^6}, {2333.67, 
  8.4827*10^6}, {2333.68, 8.4793*10^6}, {2333.69, 
  8.47589*10^6}, {2333.7, 8.47248*10^6}, {2333.71, 
  8.46907*10^6}, {2333.71, 8.46565*10^6}, {2333.72, 
  8.46223*10^6}, {2333.72, 8.4588*10^6}, {2333.73, 
  8.45537*10^6}, {2333.73, 8.45194*10^6}, {2333.73, 
  8.4485*10^6}, {2333.73, 8.44506*10^6}, {2333.73, 
  8.44161*10^6}, {2333.73, 8.43816*10^6}, {2333.73, 
  8.43471*10^6}, {2333.72, 8.43125*10^6}, {2333.72, 
  8.42779*10^6}, {2333.71, 8.42432*10^6}, {2333.71, 
  8.42085*10^6}, {2333.7, 8.41738*10^6}, {2333.69, 
  8.4139*10^6}, {2333.69, 8.41042*10^6}, {2333.68, 
  8.40693*10^6}, {2333.66, 8.40344*10^6}, {2333.65, 
  8.39995*10^6}, {2333.64, 8.39645*10^6}, {2333.63, 
  8.39295*10^6}, {2333.61, 8.38944*10^6}, {2333.6, 
  8.38593*10^6}, {2333.58, 8.38242*10^6}, {2333.56, 
  8.3789*10^6}, {2333.55, 8.37538*10^6}, {2333.53, 
  8.37185*10^6}, {2333.51, 8.36832*10^6}, {2333.48, 
  8.36479*10^6}, {2333.46, 8.36125*10^6}, {2333.44, 
  8.35771*10^6}, {2333.41, 8.35416*10^6}, {2333.39, 
  8.35061*10^6}, {2333.36, 8.34706*10^6}, {2333.34, 
  8.3435*10^6}, {2333.31, 8.33994*10^6}, {2333.28, 
  8.33637*10^6}, {2333.25, 8.3328*10^6}, {2333.22, 
  8.32923*10^6}, {2333.19, 8.32565*10^6}, {2333.16, 
  8.32207*10^6}, {2333.12, 8.31848*10^6}, {2333.09, 
  8.31489*10^6}, {2333.06, 8.3113*10^6}, {2333.02, 
  8.3077*10^6}, {2332.98, 8.3041*10^6}, {2332.95, 
  8.30049*10^6}, {2332.91, 8.29688*10^6}, {2332.87, 
  8.29327*10^6}, {2332.83, 8.28965*10^6}, {2332.79, 
  8.28603*10^6}, {2332.74, 8.2824*10^6}, {2332.7, 
  8.27877*10^6}, {2332.66, 8.27514*10^6}, {2332.61, 
  8.2715*10^6}, {2332.55, 8.26786*10^6}, {2332.48, 
  8.26421*10^6}, {2332.42, 8.26056*10^6}, {2332.35, 
  8.25691*10^6}, {2332.29, 8.25325*10^6}, {2332.22, 
  8.24959*10^6}, {2332.15, 8.24592*10^6}, {2332.08, 
  8.24225*10^6}, {2332.01, 8.23858*10^6}, {2331.94, 
  8.2349*10^6}, {2331.87, 8.23122*10^6}, {2331.79, 
  8.22753*10^6}, {2331.72, 8.22384*10^6}, {2331.64, 
  8.22015*10^6}, {2331.57, 8.21645*10^6}, {2331.49, 
  8.21275*10^6}, {2331.42, 8.20904*10^6}, {2331.34, 
  8.20533*10^6}, {2331.26, 8.20162*10^6}, {2331.18, 
  8.1979*10^6}, {2331.1, 8.19418*10^6}, {2331.02, 
  8.19045*10^6}, {2330.94, 8.18672*10^6}, {2330.85, 
  8.18299*10^6}, {2330.77, 8.17925*10^6}, {2330.68, 
  8.17551*10^6}, {2330.6, 8.17176*10^6}, {2330.51, 
  8.16801*10^6}, {2330.43, 8.16426*10^6}, {2330.34, 
  8.1605*10^6}, {2330.25, 8.15674*10^6}, {2330.16, 
  8.15297*10^6}, {2330.07, 8.1492*10^6}, {2329.98, 
  8.14543*10^6}, {2329.89, 8.14165*10^6}, {2329.79, 
  8.13787*10^6}, {2329.7, 8.13408*10^6}, {2329.6, 
  8.13029*10^6}, {2329.51, 8.1265*10^6}}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your data does not represent a function.  I believe you will need to parametrize, like this:

```
data2 = MapIndexed[{#2, #} &, data];

f = Interpolation[data2]
```

> ```
> InterpolatingFunction[{{1.,900.}},<>]
> ```

```
ParametricPlot[Log @ f[x], {x, 1, 900}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Good grief, you couldn't wait a couple of minutes?

Comment: @Daniel Believe it or not, I did. :D

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Rest assured, you're not alone :-(

Comment: @Sjoerd you shouldn't let my terse answer stop you from posting your own.

Comment: I undeleted. To me it looked very similar but maybe the differences will help someone. I'm more partial to yours though.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard My answer would have been practically identical to Daniel's. Yours is only slightly different.

Comment: Actually yours has the advantage of correctly treating the repeated x coordinates. My deleting them really is not the right thing to do. I think I'll redelete my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the swift reply. I understand your approach but could you enlighten me as to why interpolation of the form `Interpolation[{{x1,f1},{x2,f2},...}]` does not work?

Comment: @froume If there are two *y* values for one *x* value which is it supposed to return for that particular *x* value?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard My list is of the form {{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...} though, is it not? Each {xi,yi} represents a point and the interpolation should be able to interpolate between each one.

Comment: @froume `Interpolation` builds a [*function*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Function.html).  Please review that page.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Ah, there's my mistake! Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I, too, failed to answer before you last night. For what it's worth, I think a switch of x-y axes will do here (i.e. `Reverse/@data`) and it seems quicker than indexing the whole dataset.

Comment: @gpap I thought of that too, but it seemed to me that it was not the right way to approach this.  With that method you need to know and plot over the range of the function rather than the domain; further, it is a limited solution because you could have a curve that doubled back on itself in both dimensions.