# Interpolation Problem

Tags: interpolation

I have the following list:

```
AA1 = {{55.3346, 694.253}, {55.3373, 691.275}, {55.34, 
   688.323}, {55.3426, 685.396}, {55.3453, 682.494}, {55.348, 
   679.617}, {55.3506, 676.765}, {55.3533, 673.936}, {55.356, 
   671.131}, {55.3565, 668.277}, {55.3565, 665.428}, {55.3565, 
   662.604}, {55.3565, 659.803}}
```

By interpolating the data, I get an error:

```
AA2 = Interpolation[AA1, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
```

"Interpolation::inddp: The point 55.3565` in dimension 1 is duplicated. >>"

Therefore, I want to delete the duplicated terms:

```
DeleteDuplicates[AA1[[All, 1]]]
```

But how do I merge these values with the **correct** values of the second part in list AA1  (694.253 until 659.803?

Comment: Based on what criterion do you chose what you call **correct** values? You can use `Mean /@ GatherBy[AA1, First]` and you get an average of the points with duplicate values.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [(20994)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20994/121)

Answer (score 6):

**Update**:

Added below as appendix comparing 3 methods to do this: Using `MapIndexed` as shown by Mr.Wizard [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20994/interpolation-on-large-2d-list-results-in-erratic-function)  and using `GatherBy` as suggested by gpap above, and the `Union` method shown here.

```
AA1 = Union[AA1, SameTest -> (#1[[1]] == #2[[1]] &)]
Interpolation[AA1, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
```

(I do not know what you mean by merging afterwords?)

The above will use Union property that no duplicates remain, but only one copy of the duplicates is left. Using `DeleteDuplicates` will remove all duplicates.  So, this way you do not have to put anything back to the list.

Here is an example:

```
a= {{1, 2}, {1, 4}, {2, 4}}
Union[a, SameTest -> (#1[[1]] == #2[[1]] &)]

(*  {{1, 2}, {2, 4}}  *)
```

### Appendix

This shows how to use the 3 methods

```
original = {{55.3346, 694.253}, {55.3373, 691.275}, {55.34, 
    688.323}, {55.3426, 685.396}, {55.3453, 682.494}, {55.348, 
    679.617}, {55.3506, 676.765}, {55.3533, 673.936}, {55.356, 
    671.131}, {55.3565, 668.277}, {55.3565, 665.428}, {55.3565, 
    662.604}, {55.3565, 659.803}};
originalUnion = Union[original, SameTest -> (#1[[1]] == #2[[1]] &)];
originalGather = Mean /@ GatherBy[original, First];
originalMap = MapIndexed[{#2, #} &, original];

fGather = Interpolation[originalUnion, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
fUnion = Interpolation[originalUnion, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
fMap = Interpolation[originalMap, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
```

Now there are plotted

```
opts = {GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
   Frame -> True, ImagePadding -> {{30, None}, {30, 30}}};

Grid[{
  {

  Plot[fUnion[x], {x, First@fUnion[[1, 1]], Last@fUnion[[1, 1]]},Evaluate@opts, 
    FrameLabel -> {{None, None}, {x, "Union Method"}}], 

   Plot[fGather[x], {x, First@fGather[[1, 1]], Last@fGather[[1, 1]]}, Evaluate@opts, 
    FrameLabel -> {{None, None}, {x, "Gather Method"}}], 

   ParametricPlot[fMap[x], {x, First@fMap[[1, 1]], Last@fMap[[1, 1]]}, 
    AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, Evaluate@opts, 
    FrameLabel -> {{None, None}, {x, "Parametric Method"}}]

  }}, Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]