# ListDensityPlot crashes the kernel

Tags: plotting, bugs, crash

```
ListDensityPlot[
 Flatten[Table[{i, j, Sin[i + j]}, {i, 1, 20}, {j, 1, 20}], 1]]
```

gives the expected result, but a linear scale crashes my kernel (please save your work before trying)

```
ListDensityPlot[
 Flatten[Table[{i*1.*^15, j, Sin[i + j]}, {i, 1, 20}, {j, 1, 20}], 1]]
```

why? And how to fix it?
I'm using OS X 10.9.

Here is the screen crop.

[image]

Comment: Have you written support@wolfram.com about this?

Comment: Same thing happens here. I backed off from the 10^15 and it plotted fine at 10^5 but crashed at 10^7...

Comment: @rcollyer not yet, just want to see wether it's reproducible before reporting it.

Comment: @xslittlegrass In general, if you have a crash you can reproduce on *your* machine easily, always report it to Wolfram. Sometimes the issue comes from a very specific configuration of your hardware and still Wolfram should know about it. Btw, on my Ubuntu I have a crash too with your code.

Comment: @halirutan got it, I'll report to Wolfram now :)

Comment: Related to [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19253/862) I think.

Comment: @SimonWoods I tried the "DelaunayDomainScaling" method, but it gives a blank plot.

Comment: By any chance, did you report this to Wolfram?

Comment: @rcollyer Yes, here is the reply I just get from Wolfram:

Comment: reply from wolfram: "I would like to confirm that you really do want your x-values in the form
i*1.*^15
i.e. numbers like 1.*10^15, 2.*10^15 and so on.
 
If this is indeed what you want then I see that Mathematica does have a problem trying to generate a density plot with your array. It seems to be handling x-values upto 1.*10^5 but from 1.*10^6 onwards it is unable to create the plot and crashes.I have alerted the associated development team about this issue and also recorded your contact details in my report. We will keep you posted as and when a resolution becomes available."

Comment: I am having the same problem with Mathematica 9, any resolutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to xslittlegrass this reply was received from WRI:

> I would like to confirm that you really do want your x-values in the
>   form i*1.*^15 i.e. numbers like 1.*10^15, 2.*10^15 and so on. If this
>   is indeed what you want then I see that *Mathematica* does have a
>   problem trying to generate a density plot with your array. It seems to
>   be handling x-values up to 1.*10^5 but from 1.*10^6 onwards it is
>   unable to create the plot and crashes.  I have alerted the associated
>   development team about this issue and also recorded your contact
>   details in my report. We will keep you posted as and when a resolution
>   becomes available.