# kernel shuts down during listplot

Tags: memory, kernel

In at least the following situations, I have experienced that the kernel has shut down during evaluation. The thing is that there is no message at all when it shuts down.

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
temp = Partition[Flatten[Import["temp.dat", "Table"]], 3];
ResetDirectory[];

ListContourPlot[temp]
```

P.S. The file `temp.dat` is in the following link: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7611247/temp.dat.

**Why has the kernel shut down without any warning message?
What can I check or how can I fix it?**

Comment: Could you please edit your post and include the simplest example of the suspect code that is causing the kernel to crash?

Comment: Yes, I will. but nothing special.

Comment: Even though I reduce the precision or accuracy of numbers in data, the problem wasn't solved.

Comment: Possible duplicate: "[Plotting a 3D list causes kernel to crash if x and y axes have vastly different scales](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19253/280)."

Comment: Or try `ListContourPlot[temp, DataRange -> All]`?

Comment: Also, this happens if the dataset is too large and data isn't on a regular grid (at least it did on v8).

Comment: @cormullion Actually data is not on a regular grid. So the option "DataRange->All" doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov It may be helpful. I will see.

Comment: @gpap dataset is not too large, but isn't on a regular grid. I'm using v9 by the way.

Comment: I thanks all comments. I realized data not on a regular grid is the problem.