# ListContourPlot memory problems?

Tags: plotting, crash

I have a simple 3d dataset (size 7035 x 3, I put it on my site if you want to check) which I want to plot with ListContourPlot:

```
x = Import["http://www.inrim.it/~magni/a.dat"];
ListContourPlot[x, PlotRange -> {All, {0, 6}}]
```

... and so far so good.
But the x scale must - for various reasons - be rescaled, so I did this:

```
ListContourPlot[x /. {H_, f_, s_} -> {H*80, f, s}, PlotRange -> {All, {0, 6}}]
```

and M is unable to complete: after some seconds it exits *without errors*, and I discover the kernel has quit!

Comment: Same. Very strange.

Comment: Kernel crash reproduced in Dell Latitude E6520 2.4GHz  8Gb RAM, Windows 7 SP1 64 bit, Mathematica 9.0.1.0.

Comment: Try using the option `Method -> {"DelaunayDomainScaling" -> True}` (see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19330/862))

Comment: thank you Simon, that worked - though it's really slow compared with the unscaled plot. BTW, I'm on v9.0.1, Linux

Comment: No problem on WinXP V9.0.1.0

Answer (score 1):

This may be not a direct answer to your question,  and you can try to use GeometricTransformation

```
x = Import["http://www.inrim.it/~magni/a.dat"];
g= ListContourPlot[x, PlotRange -> {All, {0, 6}}]
Graphics[GeometricTransformation[g[[1]], ScalingTransform[{80, 1}]], 
   AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {All, {0, 6}}]
```