# Strange extrapolation in ListContourPlot?

Tags: graphics, interpolation

I have some Table of  `{x,y,z}` values (energy as a function of 
radial and azimuthal frequencies in a galaxy if you care to know):

```
dat = Import["https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/659996/odd-data.m"];
```

If I plot the position of the `{x,y}`

```
pl1 = Most /@ Flatten[dat, 1] // ListPlot
```

I get this

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that there is nothing pathological in the distribution of points as seen from this 3D view

```
Map[{Hue[#[[3]]], Point[#]} &, Flatten[dat, 1]] // Graphics3D
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If I now plot contours of `z[x,y]`, I get that:

```
pl2 = ListContourPlot[Flatten[dat, 1], PlotLegends -> Automatic,PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**PROBLEM**

Now the puzzling fact is that it seems *Mathematica* gives me contours 
at values of `{x,y}` which I have not sampled. 
This is best seen in the superposition:

```
Show[pl2, pl1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

e.g. for values of `x=0.3 y=0.175`.

**QUESTION**

> Is this a bug?

or am I missing something obvious?

**UPDATE**

I guess *Mathematica* cannot guess any obvious boundary to my sets of `x,y` coordinates other than the Convex Hull has mentioned by @belisarius so the Bug is in my head.

Comment: @belisarius indeed it does but you find it makes sense to extrapolate on the convex hull?

Comment: Looks like the correct partition of the space based on $z$ values, which needn't conform to the sampling of the (x,y) space, any more than the elevation of a mountain range must conform to the sampling of latitude and longitude.

Comment: See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/69102/193

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to restrict the plotting region by using `RegionFunction`.  However, it is also necessary to construct a concave hull of the data, and use a higher `MaxPlotPoints` when making the contour plot.  Using RunnyKine's code from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/88769/9490) to construct the region,

```
dat = Flatten[
   Import["https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/659996/odd-data.m"], 1];
reg = alphaShapes2D[DeleteDuplicates@dat[[All, ;; 2]], .33];
RegionPlot[reg]
```

[image]

We can now get the proper contour plot,

```
Show[
 ListContourPlot[dat, PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, RegionMember[reg, {x, y}]], 
  MaxPlotPoints -> 100],
 ListPlot@dat[[All, ;; 2]]
 ]
```

[image]