# MeshCoordinates from a RegionBoundary no longer in proper order in version 10.4

Tags: bugs, computational-geometry

**Bug introduced in V10.4 and persists through 10.4.1**

---

Given that I have the following data set

```
mat = 
 {{{0.,-5.,0.},{-5.22027,0.,1.79454}},
 {{-0.858274,-4.93844,0.0924},{-5.41893,0.782172,1.77784}}, 
 {{-1.82027,-4.75528,-0.109357},{-5.60223,1.54509,1.95084}},
 {{-2.94275,-4.45503,-0.550252},{-5.77547,2.26995,2.3602}},
 {{-4.31974,-4.04509,-1.18618},{-5.94562,2.93893,3.03783}},
 {{-6.12372,-3.53553,-2.00001},{-6.12372,3.53553,3.99999}}};

domain = 
  {{{5.0165, 2 Pi}, {0, 0.756304}}, {{3.4076, 2 Pi}, {0, 2.31521}}, 
   {{3.7396, 2 Pi}, {0, 1.93244}}, {{3.85122, 2 Pi}, {0, 1.86739}},  
   {{3.91005, 2 Pi}, {0, 1.87528}}, {{3.94139, 2 Pi}, {0, 1.91028}}};

ellipsePoints[mat_, {x_, y_}] := 
  mat.{Sin[#], Cos[#], 1} & /@ Range[x, y, 0.02 Pi]
ellipsePoints[mat_, {{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}}] := 
  mat.{Sin[#], Cos[#], 1} & /@ 
   Join[Range[a, b, 0.02 Pi], Range[c, d, 0.02 Pi]]

pts = Flatten[MapThread[ellipsePoints, {mat, domain}], 1];
```

With help of RunnyKine's [`alphaShapes2DC[]`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88752/delaunaymesh-in-a-specified-closed-region-creating-a-concave-hull-from-a-set-o/88769#88769) function, I can find the approximate boundary

```
Show[Graphics[Point[pts]], RegionBoundary@alphaShapes2DC[pts, 5.5]]
```

[image]

---

However, when I get the coordinates of the boundary via `MeshCoordinates[]`, which gives me a wrong order of point-set.

```
ListLinePlot@MeshCoordinates@RegionBoundary@alphaShapes2DC[pts, 5.5]
```

[image]

So my question is:(I using the *Mathematica* V$10.4$ on Windows $32$ bit system)

- How to do to achieve the right order of point-set?

Comment: What version are you using?  When I run that last line I get the correct result:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/tfiZM.png

Comment: @JasonB I using the *Mathematica* V$10.4$ on Windows 32 bit system.

Comment: I can verify that this works great on 10.0 through 10.3.1, but not 10.4

Comment: @JasonB OK, thansks for your testing:) It should be a bug introduced in the latest version $10.4$.

Comment: Yeah, I'm working on a workaround right now.  I could reformulate the question to be easy for others to verify, as in it doesn't need to even refer to `alphapoints` function, it applies to any `BoundaryMeshRegion`.

Comment: @JasonB I tried the `FindCurvePath[]` just now, but this built-in failed to find the continuous curve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at a simpler example to show the problem.  We'll create a Delaunay mesh from some random points, and generate a `RegionBoundary` from that.

In version 10.4:

```
SeedRandom[4];
mr1 = DelaunayMesh[RandomReal[1, {15, 2}]];
mr2 = RegionBoundary[mr1];
Show[mr1, HighlightMesh[mr2, 1], 
 ListLinePlot[MeshCoordinates@mr2, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red]]]
```

[image: 10.4 output]

compared with version 10.3.1 (or any previous version 10.x)

[image: output from earlier versions]

Let's look at the `InputForm` for this in 10.4,

```
mr2 // InputForm


MeshRegion[{.....}, {Line[{{2, 6}, {1, 2}, {4, 1}, {3, 5}, {6, 3}, {5, 4}}]}]
```

versus for 10.3,

```
MeshRegion[{.....}, {Line[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {6,1}}]}]
```

How to get around this?  Create a `BoundaryMeshRegion` and extract the polygon points from that (the points of a polygon **must** be in the right order or it's nonsense).  The following gives identical results in 10.3 and 10.4

```
SeedRandom[4];
mr1 = DelaunayMesh[RandomReal[1, {15, 2}]];
mr2 = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[mr1];
Show[mr1, HighlightMesh[mr2, 1], 
 ListLinePlot[First@First@MeshPrimitives[mr2, 2], 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red]]]
```

[image: fixed version]

And, applied to the OP,

```
ListLinePlot@First@First@MeshPrimitives[#, 2] &@
 BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@alphaShapes2DC[pts, 5.5]
```

[image: the alpha shape]

Comment: So the algorithm has changed in V$10.4$.