# Extract a region from a list of points

Tags: regions

I need to extract a region out of a list of points. My points are displayed as follows:[image: My ListPlot]

I have divided the points in three different regions and then joined them, R1, R2 and R3 are the list of points for each of the three regions. Then I execute the code:

```
aux1 = ConvexHullMesh[R1];

aux2 = ConvexHullMesh[R2];

aux3 = ConvexHullMesh[R3];

R = RegionUnion[aux1, aux2, aux3];
```

And the result is:

[image: Final region]

So I have two problems: In the left region it is not taking into account the 'hole' and in the right side ones it is doing a convex region (as the command i used is convex). I have tried other commands but none of them work as expected. Any idea?

Comment: It might be helpful to give a link to your dataset

Comment: You have to set some intelligently chosen limit to what is considered to be a hole and what not. My first thought on this would be to consider all triangles formed of sides (= pairs of points) of length less than some constant value. To form a list of such candidate points you can use `Nearest` (with some deduplication of entries). After this, you should be able to create a (boundary) mesh of these regions. (I'm not saying this method is necessarily particularly efficient...)

Comment: What you need is the [alpha shape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_shape) of these regions, a sort of concave hull.  You can use either of the answers [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88752/9490) and get it right away.

Comment: JasonB answer worked perfectly! Thanks a lot

Comment: @Salva - glad to help!  This will probably get marked as a duplicate then, but feel free to come back and participate more in the future