# Error in Mesh Region during concave hull

Tags: plotting, warning-messages, mesh

I have the following data:
[Data.csv](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kgFIKG9xFFpJyOEnYuNm-1d_Lm1b35vk)

It crates the following image:

[image]

Im trying to make a concave hull so that I can create an outline of the region. I have tried to use all versions of the `alphaShapes2D` code found in this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88752/delaunaymesh-in-a-specified-closed-region-creating-a-concave-hull-from-a-set-o/88769#88769). I think have pinpointed the issue, it seems my points are too close. In the latest versions of the code it create a "complex infinity". While in the first version it just creates incredibly large numbers, when computing the radii of the tetrahedrons. I tried to manually remove these error by adding another line to the code. Each time it creates the error `MeshRegion::dgcellr: Degenerate cells including Polygon[{22,19,21}] have been removed.`

Any ideas how to make this work?

So if I edit the data to delete duplicates, which I overlooked. The edited code works. However the latest version  `alphaShapes2DC` still outputs the same error even if the duplicates are removed.

P.S. Here is the version of the code I tried to modify:

```
 alphaShapes2D[points_, crit_] := Module[{alphacriteria, del =Quiet@DelaunayMesh@points, 
 tetras,tetcoords, tetradii, tetradii2, selectExternalFaces}, 
 alphacriteria[tetrahedra_, radii_, rmax_] := 
 Pick[tetrahedra, UnitStep@Subtract[rmax, radii], 1];
 selectExternalFaces[facets_] := MeshRegion[points, facets];
 If[Head[del] === EmptyRegion, del, tetras = MeshCells[del, 2];
 tetcoords = MeshPrimitives[del, 2][[All, 1]];
 tetradii = Quiet@Thread[Circumsphere[tetcoords]][[All, 2]];
 tetradii2 = If[# < 1, #, 1] & /@ tetradii;
 selectExternalFaces@alphacriteria[tetras, tetradii2, crit]]
 ]
```

Comment: @Henrik Its linked, just click on "Data.csv" should go to google drive.

Comment: Oh, sorry, bad eyes today...^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were some duplicated points which induced division by zero when their distance popped up as a dividend somewhere. I also sprayed in some additional points in the interior to prevent that the middle of the figure is "thinned" out too fast.

```
a = Developer`ToPackedArray[N@Import["borderdata.csv", "Data"]];
x = Join[
   DeleteDuplicates[a],
   ConstantArray[0., {1, 2}],
   CirclePoints[{0.015, 0}, 16],
   CirclePoints[{0.0075, Pi/8}, 8]
   ];
Show[alphaShapes2D[x, 0.006], Graphics[Point[x]]]
```

[image]

I am not sure though whether this is what you wanted to achieve.