# Plot geologic profile of layers

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning

I am trying to plot a set of layers with different values of densities (density profile). Geometry (`{x,z}` values) of 15 interfaces of layers look like this:
[image]

while the first interface is a planar surface. `{x, z}` values and densities of individual interfaces can be found [here](https://filebin.net/71mqg30pelx5nc4x).

I tried to use `ArrayPlot`. Here is my attempt:

```
(*read data*)
ninterf = 15;
interfaces = 
Table[Import["interface_" <> ToString[i] <> ".dat", "Table"], {i, 1,
 ninterf}];
densities = Flatten[Import["den.dat", "Table"]];

rangex = MinMax[#[[1]] & /@ interfaces[[1]]]
rangez = {Min[#[[2]] & /@ interfaces[[-1]]], 
Max[#[[2]] & /@ interfaces[[1]]]}

(*interpolate data*)
f = Table[Unique[f$], {i, 1, ninterf}];
Table[f[[i]] = Interpolation[interfaces[[i]], InterpolationOrder -> 1], {i, 
1, ninterf}];
F = Through@*f;

(*create a grid of {x,z} values for ArrayPlot*)
step = 1.;
xzvalues = 
Table[{N[i], N[j]}, {i, rangex[[1]], rangex[[2]], step}, {j, 
rangez[[2]], rangez[[1]], -step}];

(*determine density for every point of the grid*)
densityfunc[xval_, zval_] := 
Module[{numb = 
Last[Flatten[Position[F[N[xval]], _?(# >= N[zval] &)]]]}, 
densities[[numb]]];

values = Apply[densityfunc, #, {1}] & /@ xzvalues;

(*Show result-ArrayPlot*)
ArrayPlot[Transpose[values], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

Here is the final picture-**density profile**

[image]

The time needed for calculation of `values` on my computer is **689.04** seconds (for bigger models, e.g. 5 times bigger, this might take a lot of time). In this case, I set the grid spacing `step=1.` since interfaces should look smooth. With bigger `step` the calculation time would be shorter but interfaces would not be smooth enough.

I would like to speed up the evaluation of `values`(if it is possible; parallelization of code would be also welcomed) or maybe someone knows faster way how to get similiar picture of density profile. I will be grateful for any suggestions.

**UPDATE**: Carl Lange and kglr proposed using `Filling` which works great for this simple model of 15 interfaces. Could be `Filling` used also for this complex model of layers?
[image]

The data for this complex model can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6ggj1r15zs9dq7e/AAAfPw4hZCMcvsuw9t3Rch65a?dl=0).

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what's going on here - perhaps you can post a little more context and some of your data. It seems like what you're generating can be achieved just by using `Filling`, but I think I'm just misunderstanding your exact problem and intention.

Comment: @CarlLange I forgot about `Filling`.Thank you. Yes, in this case it solves my problem. I just need to think about it little more. Maybe is not applicable for all configurations (more complex density profiles).

Comment: see also [StackedListPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StackedListPlot.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested in the comments we can use `ListLinePlot` with `Filling` like so:

```
ListLinePlot[
  interfaces,
  PlotStyle -> ({CapForm["Butt"], #} & /@ Map[ColorData["Rainbow"], Rescale[densities]]),
  Filling -> Bottom,
  FillingStyle -> Opacity[1]
]
```

[image]

`Filling` will extrude your curve in the vertical direction, and so your other dataset comes out more jagged with this approach:
[image]

To fix this, I will clean the data, then isolate and color each face manually. Since these faces will have edges of different colors, I choose the median of the face vertex colors.

First I convert our scene into a mesh, then find all unconnected endpoints. We'll need to close these up somehow.

```
lines = DiscretizeGraphics[Line /@ interfaces];
coords = MeshCoordinates[lines];
bds = Flatten[Position[Differences[lines["ConnectivityMatrix"[0, 1]]["RowPointers"]], 1]];
```

Let's pause and look at these endpoints. It's clear there's some that really shouldn't be there:

```
Show[
  MeshRegion[lines, PlotTheme -> "Lines"], 
  Graphics[{Red, MeshPrimitives[lines, {0, bds}]}], 
  AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio
]
```

[image]

We'll need to clean up the original data a bit. I notice the endpoints we'd like to clean are all within 5.2 of another vertex, and the endpoints we want to keep are not (except for one). I will group these nearby points and merge them by taking the mean:

```
neardata = Nearest[
  MeshCoordinates[lines] -> {"Index", "Element"}, 
  MeshCoordinates[lines][[bds]], 
  {All, 5.2}
];

(coords[[#1]] = ConstantArray[#2, Length[#1]]) & @@@ MapAt[Mean, Transpose /@ neardata, {All, 2}];
lines = MeshRegion[coords, MeshCells[lines, 1]];
bds = Flatten[Position[Differences[lines["ConnectivityMatrix"[0, 1]]["RowPointers"]], 1]];
```

We'll now connect up the endpoints. If the set was convex, we'd use `ConvexHullMesh`. Instead we could find an [alpha-shape](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/109999/4346), but something like `FindShortestTour` seems to work just fine.

```
boundary = FindShortestTour[MeshCoordinates[lines][[bds]]][[2]];
envelope = MeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[lines][[bds]], Line[boundary]];
Show[
  MeshRegion[lines, PlotTheme -> "Lines"], 
  MeshRegion[envelope, MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> Red}, PlotTheme -> "Lines"], 
  AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio
]
```

[image]

Let's join these up and find faces using [IGraphM](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM):

```
Needs["IGraphM`"];
tofill = RegionUnion[lines, envelope];
faces = Rest[IGFaces[IGMeshGraph[tofill]]];
```

Now color each face:

```
colors = Rescale[Sort[densities]];
cnf = Nearest[Catenate[MapThread[Thread[#1 -> #2] &, {interfaces, colors}]]];
coords2 = MeshCoordinates[tofill];

Graphics[
  GraphicsComplex[
    coords2, 
    Map[
      {
        EdgeForm[{Thin, GrayLevel[.2]}], 
        ColorData["Rainbow"][Median[Flatten[cnf[coords2[[#]]]]]], 
        Polygon[#]
      }&, 
      faces
    ]
  ], 
  AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write an elaborate answer for me. I think that this answer fuly accomplished what I need. Right now, I am trying to reproduce your code, but this first line of code `lines=DiscretizeGraphics[Line[interfaces]];` gives me this error: `DiscretizeGraphics: Graphics primitives with coordinates are not supported`.

Comment: @Moonwalk it’s possible older versions couldn’t discretize the scene. What version are you using?

Comment: I am using 11.2.0.0. I have not downloaded my update to 11.3 yet.

Comment: @Moonwalk Looks like `lines = DiscretizeGraphics[Line /@ interfaces];` works in 11.2. I went ahead and made this change in my post. The rest worked for me in 11.2.

Comment: Really nice answer, very graceful!

Comment: @CarlLange thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
ifs = Interpolation[#, InterpolationOrder -> 1] & /@ interfaces;
xrange = MinMax[interfaces[[All, All, 1]]]; 
Plot[Evaluate[Append[Through@ifs@x,  1.05 Min[interfaces[[All, All, -1]]]]],
 {x, xrange[[1]], xrange[[2]]}, 
 Axes -> False, ImageSize -> Large, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotStyle -> (Append[Directive[CapForm["Butt"], Thick, #] & /@ 
    (ColorData["Rainbow"] /@Rescale[densities]), None]), 
 Filling -> Thread[Range[15] -> List /@ Range[2, 16]], 
 FillingStyle -> Opacity[1]]
```

[image]