# Highlighting a region containing a scatter plot

Tags: plotting, filling

I have obtained the plot shown below using

```
ListLogLogPlot[Table[{Abs[a1[[i]]], Abs[a2[[i]]]}, {i, 400}]
```

I want to fill the whole region containing the scattered points as shown by the lines I have drawn by hand. Is it possible?

[image]

The appearance of the scattered points, themselves, is not mandatory in the plot.

I want to produce a similar kind of smooth plot like this.[image: Ignore the legend "Normal"]

Comment: You are much more likely to get help if you supplied the data that can be used to reproduce your plot. Also, unless you can describe how to generate the boundary line mathematically or in code, there is no answer.

Comment: I can share data file if you want.  Can I give an error to each boundary points and plot it as a boundary line?

Comment: You know the boundary points? Edit your question to include your method for determining them.

Comment: I don't know the boundary points.

Comment: Well, that is the crux of the matter. There is no solution unless the boundary can be specified in a form that Mathematica understands..

Comment: here 'a2' is a function of 'a1' other parameters. I have varied 'a1' from '10^-6' to '10' and plotted them against 'a2'.

Comment: can I use other plot comments to get the filling region rathar than ListLogLogPlot. ?

Comment: Is your problem filling in between the borders on your plot, or is it finding the borders?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DelaunayMesh in a specified closed region - creating a concave hull from a set of points](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88752/delaunaymesh-in-a-specified-closed-region-creating-a-concave-hull-from-a-set-o)

Comment: filling the whole region that is scattered is the objective. so filling in between the borders might help

Comment: @corey979 , nope that does hot help. I want it within the frame

Comment: Maybe @AntonAntonov will swoop in with an answer...

Comment: If there was any data to work with I might (a) replace each point by a small disk and (b) fiddle around with `Dilation` and `Erosion` until I got either a pleasing result or so frustrated I opened a bottle of scotch.

Comment: Your added, vague, constraint requiring smoothness only makes your question harder to answer without precise specification of what is acceptable boundary curve.

Answer (score 1):

Given what you have said, the only thing I can think of is to use Mathematica's graphics drawing tools to draw the boundary freehand, extract the boundary points from the modified graphic, and convert it into a polygon. Here is an example.

Contrived data and plot for example.

```
SeedRandom[42]; data = RandomInteger[99, {100, 2}];
ListPlot[data, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[5]]
```

[image: unmarked_plot]

I now use the drawing tools to draw a boundary around some points.

[image: marked_plot]

I then assign the marked plot to a variable.

[image: assign]

Finally, I make a new plot with boundary line converted to a polygon.

```
markedPlot /. Line[pts___] -> {Blue, Opacity[.4], Polygon[pts]}
```

[image: hilited_plot]

Comment: Thank you for ur effort. I have modified the question and added another image which might help you understand my problem.