# Does List DensityPlot with RegionFunction use the convex Hull?

Tags: plotting, regions

As it says, I am using ListDensityPlot (in 10.4), where the data is only defined on a dumbbell shaped region.

[image: As shown below]

ListDensityPlot does the following:

[image: ListDenistyPlot result]

which clearly works on the convex hull. To test, I added a regionFunction to the Plot, and draw the outline in red. So how do I only draw on the *inside* of the dumbbell?

Comment: Use `RegionFunction` with whatever generated your first plot to restrict the plot to your domain of interest. But then, where is the code for generating your region?

Comment: `insidedumb[i_, j_, r_, o_, 
  d_] := (i - r - o)^2 + j^2 <= r^2 \[Or] (i + r + o)^2 + j^2 <= 
   r^2 \[Or] (-o <= i <= o \[And] -d <= j <= d)`

Comment: Also, I did add this as a RegionFunction option to my LstDensityPlot. No effect!

Comment: You need to provide a minimal working example. That is; the code that defines your dumbbell region, a set of data, and the `ListDensityPlot` code that creates the plot.

Comment: Unless code is given to show how it's different, then I would mark this as a duplicate of [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73188/9490).  The answer posted there *should* work perfectly for this example as well.

Comment: Sorry for not adding the full code; it is somewhat of a beast.

Comment: The reason is that the `RegionFunction` option has no effect. I will see whether I can book this down to a simple case. The code itself is rather involved.

Comment: I agree the question marked as duplicate has the same problem; the difference is that RegionFunction in ListDensityPlot also use the complex hull.

Answer (score 1):

OK,
A first partial answer can be found from deep in the documentation (under Options->Mesh): "The entire mesh for irregular data is a Delaunay triangulation". My mesh is of course not irregular; my boundary is, and what I see is a Delaunay triangulation of my mesh. The surprise is that using the RegionFunction still shows the whole mesh, including parts outside the region.

A solution is to overlay the plot with the negation of the function that tests whether points are inside `RegionPlot[\[Not] in[i, j], {i, -xm, xm}, {j, -ym, ym}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, White], BoundaryStyle->None]`.

That works, by just using `Show`.

Niels