# Parametric Density Plot

Tags: plotting, graphics

I want to combine the features of the functions `DensityPlot` and `ParametricPlot`. That is, I have three functions $f(x,y)$, $g(x,y)$ and $h(x,y)$. I want to create a density plot that shows a color representing the magnitude of $h(x,y)$ at a point described by $(f(x,y), g(x,y))$ for some range of the input parameters x and y.

I have all the data analytically, so I would rather not like to use `ListDensityPlot`, since it takes a long time to create enough data for a useful plot and there is also some annoying extrapolation going on. (See also [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133914/does-list-densityplot-with-regionfunction-use-the-convex-hull).)

Is there anything built in I have overlooked? Is there an easy way to implement what I'm trying to do?
Thanks for all suggestions!

Comment: `DensityPlot[h[f[x, y], g[x, y]], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}]`?

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. I want to evaluate all the functions at {x,y} but plot the corresponding point at the position {f[x,y], g[x,y]}.
I should say that while I have the functions in an analytical form, I don't want to invert them as that is going to be messy for sure.

Comment: then, perhaps, `DensityPlot[h[x, y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}] /. 
 GraphicsComplex[a_, b___] :> 
  GraphicsComplex[a /. {x_, y_} :> {f[x, y], g[x, y]}, b]`?