# Repeated interpolation for 3D unstructured grid -> Optimization

Tags: interpolation, finite-element-method, mesh

Trying to perform mesh-to-mesh 3D interpolation on unstructured grid. Mesh size is about 200k nodes. Painful thing that interpolation shoud be repeated ~1000 times (different thermal map) on the same mesh.

One "operation" performs in less than a minute (w/ InterpolationOrder->1) --> but 1000 steps takes 12 hours. I am wondering are there any options to optimize the procedure for unstructured grid and make the whole calculation faster, cause mesh doesn`t change but it takes time to generate Denaunay triangulation at each step.

Comment: Look up ``NDSolve`FEM`ElementMeshInterpolation``.

Comment: If that's no help, then perhaps the question is not clear enough.  How is  your mesh generated? Can you provide a minimal example? What function are you trying to optimize? Might the optimal values be at the nodes (since you using linear interpolation)?  Or did you mean [tag:performance-tuning] instead of [tag:mathematical-optimization]?

Comment: There are two list of nodes (for example): `inputlist=RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {200000, 3}] ` and `outputlist=RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {200000, 3}] ` (in these example boundaries may be different, but in my case they are equal). Both lists represent unstructured grid. Another list contains data in the inputlist at different timesteps (example): `Temp=RandomInteger[{100,200},{200000,1000}]`. I made a loop with `TempFunc = Interpolation[DataTable, InterpolationOrder -> 1]` function, where `DataTable=MapThread[List, {inputlist, Temp[[istep]]}]`.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/68973/listcontourplot-interpolation-fails-if-x-and-y-axes-have-different-scales/69102#69102 (but the grid has a semi-regular structure).

Comment: Thanks, Michael E2. `NDSolve`FEM`ElementMeshInterpolation` helps. Becomes x4 faster.

Answer (score 5):

One can use generate an [`ElementMesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ElementMesh.html) once and for all (15-16 sec.); then use [`ElementMeshInterpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementProgramming.html#87460397) on each coordinate to construct interpolations (1.7 sec.).

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

SeedRandom[0];
inputlist = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {200000, 3}];
outputlist = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {200000, 3}];

( mesh = DelaunayMesh[inputlist];  
  elem = Thread[MeshCells[mesh, 3], Tetrahedron] /. 
    Tetrahedron -> TetrahedronElement;
  (*coords = MeshCoordinates[mesh];
  coords == inputlist*)
  emesh = ToElementMesh[
    "Coordinates" -> inputlist,
    "MeshElements" -> {elem}];
 ) // AbsoluteTiming

ifns = ElementMeshInterpolation[{emesh}, #, 
      "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Indeterminate &, 
        "WarningMessage" -> False}] & /@ 
    Transpose[outputlist]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*
  {15.7423, Null}
  {1.69745, Null}
*)
```

One can construct various interfaces to the interpolating functions.  The matrix one is faster on lists of points, though only by a little.

```
Clear[ifn];
ifn[v_?VectorQ] := Through[ifns @@ v];
ifn[m_?MatrixQ] := Through[ifns @@ Transpose[m]];
ifn[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := Through[ifns[x, y, z]];
```

Evaluating the interpolating function is not fast, but I assume that is probably true no matter what.  (An unstructured grid is handle by an `ElementMesh` under the hood, AFAIK.)  In any case, constructing `emesh` only once saves a lot of time.  I also am getting a small error with my last iteration.  (There wasn't any the first time I tried.)

```
ifn@inputlist[[;; 10]] - outputlist[[;; 10]] // Abs // Max // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.584745, 1.06581*10^-14}  *)
```

But there doesn't seem to be a problem with the data in the interpolating functions:

```
Table[
 {ifns[[i]]["ElementMesh"]["Coordinates"] == inputlist,
  ifns[[i]]["ValuesOnGrid"] == outputlist[[All, i]]}, {i, 3}]
(*  {{True, True}, {True, True}, {True, True}}  *)
```

I suppose it's a weakness in the internal interpolating code.