# ListDensityPlot : Strange result when dealing with large matrix

Tags: plotting, bugs

I have a transient absorption spectrum(TAS) saved as a 240x3648 matrix, I want to use `ListDensityPlot` to plot it, but something is wrong:

```
delay = Table[i*5.2`5 - 120*5`5, {i, 1, 240}];
frequency = Flatten[Import["frequency.csv"]];
spec = Import["spectrum.dat", "Data"];
spec1 = 
  Flatten[
    Table[{delay[[j]], frequency[[k]], spec[[j, k]]}, {j,1,240}, {k, 1, 3648}], 
    1];
ListDensityPlot[spec1, AxesLabel -> {"Delay", "Frequency"}]
```

The right side is totally wrong, but when I change the fourth line of the code to

```
spec1 = Flatten[Table[{j, k, spec[[j, k]]}, {j,1,240}, {k, 1, 3648}], 1];
```

then the result will be all right.

This is not what I want. Please help me!

I can't put on more than two links, but the frequency can be replaced by any 3648 array. The OneDrive link of the spectrum file: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ahthsev5X2HBhKF-fWIK7Zl6qvwjtQ   , and frequency file:https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ahthsev5X2HBhKE46K7C5eFTqtKNXA

Comment: *Mathematica* **always** makes better plots of 3D data when the data is given as an array of $z$-values, versus when you give the data as a list of $\{x, y, z\}$ tuples.   I believe in this case, you are experiencing [this bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/68973/listcontourplot-interpolation-fails-if-x-and-y-axes-have-different-scales).  Try something like `ListDensityPlot[Transpose@spec, AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
 DataRange -> {{-594.8, 648}, {1.55, 1.60}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Delay", "Frequency"}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]` instead

Comment: @Jason In the way you give out, the plot is working normally. But there is a problem: the vertical coordinates is not well-proportioned! The Y-coordinate space between different data points could be different. It is caused by the operating mode of the spectrometer and can not be changed. So...

Comment: @Jason May be I have to change the ticks by option "Ticks->{}", a laborious way.

Comment: actually I had to guess about the y axis range because the frequency csv file wasn't posted.  If your frequency data is just a linear array  of regularly spaced points, then just give the min and max values to [`DataRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DataRange.html) and the tickmarks should line up thte same

Comment: My reputation is too little so I can't post more than two links. I have delete the link for result of the plot and add the frequency file. I'm a China student, so maybe I'm in sleep but you're in daylight, sorry to respond slowly.

Comment: Did you check `MatrixPlot`? Instead of creating the table you can only adjust the `FrameTicks` to get something like a `ListDensityPlot`.

Comment: ! I will take a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is another manifestation of this bug:

- [ListContourPlot interpolation fails if x and y axes have different scales](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/68973/listcontourplot-interpolation-fails-if-x-and-y-axes-have-different-scales)

The solution for that issue is not to keep your data in the form of `{x, y, z}` tuples, but keep it as a rectangular array.  Then you can just feed the x and y ranges for the tick marks to the `DataRange` option.

```
ListDensityPlot[Transpose@spec, AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
 DataRange -> {MinMax@delay, MinMax@frequency}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Delay", "Frequency"}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

You can get just as good a plot, in much less time, if you resample the data to have fewer points.

```
resampledData = ArrayResample[ Transpose @ spec, {500, 240}];
```

Comment: Thanks. At first I want to plot with totally accurate original data from the experiment, now I think I have to use a more economical way.