# How to get derivative of 2D data that is randomly stored in x and y?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, finite-element-method, interpolation

I have 2d data in the form `{x,y,f(x,y)}` which is randomly stored.  the random `{x,y}` for specific shape (square for simplification here) can be created as

```
Regn = {{-\[Pi], -\[Pi]}, {-\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {\[Pi], -\
\[Pi]}, {-\[Pi], -\[Pi]}};
xylist=Select[RegionMember[Polygon@(Regn)]][
 Join @@ CoordinateBoundsArray[CoordinateBounds@(Regn), Into[50]]]
```

then these points are passed to a function `f` here it is just `sin` and we get

```
datxy = Table[{xylist[[i, 1]], xylist[[i, 2]], 
    Sin[xylist[[i, 1]] xylist[[i, 2]]]}, {i, 1, Length[xylist]}];
ListDensityPlot[datxy, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
```

[image]

my question is how can I plot the x or y  derivative of such data?

**Update**

here I will compare the solution provided by the answers which indicate that the built-in interpolation gives bad results compared to the method provided by @Shin Kim

[image]

I used `PlotPoints->50` in `DensityPlot` for the interpolated data

Comment: I think this is  problem of interpolation on an unstructured set of data points. [This question]https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/235681/12558 should give you an interpolation function for your problem.  You can then calculate the derivative as if you had an equation.

Comment: @Hugh, I know how to use listinterpolate for structured data..but I don't understand how the mentioned question can do that? may you please elaborate?

Comment: The comparison in the edit is useful. They all look the same to me.  It may be you are after some smoothing for your derivatives -that would be a new question.  If you have limited data you can't expect perfect derivatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to produce the derivatives directly using only the raw data,

```
(*w.r.t y*)
datxy = Sort[Sort[datxy, #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] &],
    Which[ #1[[1]] == #2[[1]] && #1[[2]] < #2[[2]], True,
           #1[[1]] == #2[[1]] && #1[[2]] > #2[[2]], False ] &];
Dy = {};
Do[If[datxy[[i, 1]] == datxy[[i + 1, 1]],
  AppendTo[Dy, Flatten@{datxy[[i, 1 ;; 2]], (datxy[[i + 1, {2, 3}]] - datxy[[i, {2, 3}]]) /. {dy_, df_} -> df/dy}]
 ], {i, Length@datxy - 1}]

(*w.r.t x*)
datxy = Sort[Sort[datxy, #1[[2]] < #2[[2]] &],
    Which[ #1[[2]] == #2[[2]] && #1[[1]] < #2[[1]], True,
           #1[[2]] == #2[[2]] && #1[[1]] > #2[[1]], False] &];
Dx = {};
Do[If[datxy[[i, 2]] == datxy[[i + 1, 2]],
  AppendTo[Dx, Flatten@{datxy[[i, 1 ;; 2]], (datxy[[i + 1, {1, 3}]] - datxy[[i, {1, 3}]]) /. {dx_, df_} -> df/dx}]
 ], {i, Length@datxy - 1}]
```

then form the gradient:

```
grad = {};
i = 1;
Do[
 Do[If[Dx[[i, 1 ;; 2]] == Dy[[j, 1 ;; 2]], 
   AppendTo[grad, {Dx[[i, 1 ;; 2]], {Dx[[i, 3]], Dy[[j, 3]]}}]],
 {j, Length@Dy}];
i++;
, Length@Dx]
ClearAll[i]
```

Following is a comparison with the actual gradient (right):

[image]

I coded this without any concern of performance, so there's a lot of room for optimization, if anyone's interested.

Answer (score 3):

You can first calculate an interpolation of your data. As your arguments are not on a grid, only Interpolation order of 1 can be used:

```
fun = Interpolation[datxy, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
```

[image]

With a function we may now calculate the derivatives like:

```
derx[x_, y_] = D[fun[x, y], x]
```

[image]

```
dery[x_, y_] = D[fun[x, y], y]
```

[image]

Comment: the results are fuzzy? kindly, see my update

Answer (score 2):

Here is my suggestion for interpolation. I start by making your data.

```
Regn = {{-π, -π}, {-π, π}, {π, π}, {π, -\
π}, {-π, -π}};
xylist = Select[RegionMember[Polygon@(Regn)]][
   Join @@ CoordinateBoundsArray[CoordinateBounds@(Regn), Into[50]]];

datxy = Table[{xylist[[i, 1]], xylist[[i, 2]], 
    Sin[xylist[[i, 1]] xylist[[i, 2]]]}, {i, 1, Length[xylist]}];
ListDensityPlot[datxy, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
```

[image]

I extract the coordinate points from your data and make a mesh.

```
pts = datxy /. {x_, y_, z_} :> {x, y};
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[pts];
```

Now I interpolate the data and we can use the interpolated data as if it was an equation or function.

```
int = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, datxy[[All, 3]]];
Plot3D[int[x, y], {x, y} ∈ mesh]
```

[image]

To take the derivative we use the usual derivative operation.

```
dx = Head[D[int[x, y], x]];
Plot3D[dx[x, y], {x, y} ∈ mesh]
```

[image]

Possibly we need some smoothing after taking the derivative but that's another question.
Hope that helps.

Comment: the results are fuzzy? kindly, see my update