# Interpolation on an unstructured grid with large aspect ratio

Tags: finite-element-method, interpolation

If you wish to interpolate on an unstructured grid then the solution is to use `ElementMeshInterpolation` from the Finite Element Method. I examined this [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/235681/12558) but now wish to take it further. In particular how to deal with the large aspect ratio.

I start by making some points I wish to interpolate.

```
pts = Table[t  {Cos[t]/100, Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 100, 0.5}];
values = {#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[1]]  #[[2]]^2} & /@ pts;
ListPlot3D[values, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

The plot is poor because of the poor underlying mesh used. This can be seen if the plot is built from first principles.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
mesh = ToElementMesh[pts];
Show[mesh["Wireframe"], AspectRatio -> 1]
int = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, values[[All, 3]]];
Plot3D[int[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, PlotRange -> All, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

[image]

The solution is to re-scale the grid points as follows

```
{x1, x2} = MinMax[pts[[All, 1]]];
{y1, y2} = MinMax[pts[[All, 2]]];
pts1 = {Rescale[#[[1]], {x1, x2}, {-1, 1}], 
     Rescale[#[[2]], {y1, y2}, {-1, 1}]} & /@ pts;
mesh1 = ToElementMesh[pts1];
Show[mesh1["Wireframe"], AspectRatio -> 1]
int1 = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh1}, values[[All, 3]]];
Plot3D[int1[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh1, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

[image]

This is much better although it could do with a few more points in the interpolation.
The problem is now to return to the original coordinates. How do I replace the re-scaled mesh coordinates by the original coordinates?

One method is to define a remapping function as follows

```
ClearAll[fint];
fint[x_, y_] := 
 int1[-1 + 2 (x - x1)/(x2 - x1), -1 + 2 (y - y1)/(y2 - y1)]
Show[Plot3D[fint[x, y], {x, x1, x2}, {y, y1, y2}, PlotRange -> All, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}],
 Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.02], Point[values]}]
 ]
```

[image]

This is reasonable but the region of plotting or using the function has been lost. I can't define the region by `{x, y} \[Element] mesh`. In particular, if you save the function for future use how do you find the region from the saved values? Can one make a better interpolation function? Is there a way of putting the original coordinate values back into the function made by `ElementMeshInterpolation`?

Thanks

Comment: Could you not map a query point to the new, scaled interpolating function in the same way you scaled the mesh coordinates?

Comment: @user21 How do I tell if a query point  is inside or outside my region? In my mapping example (last example) I do a remapping to `fint` in a way I think you are suggesting. However, I would prefer to have a new interpolation function that does not require remapping and lets me know if my point is outside the region.