# ListPlot3D. Only plots about half of the data in a 3D matrix

Tags: plotting

Here is the data and the exact command I'm trying to run.

I've had success with other datasets generated and written out to a file by the exact same program in the exact same manner but for some reason this one won't plot correctly. The only thing I can think of is that it has something to do with the large ranges of the numbers. I can't find any missing commas or otherwise incorrect syntax, however I am very new to mathematica so its likely something very simple I'm overlooking. Played around with PlotRange to no avail. Any Ideas?

[image]

```
ListPlot3D[{{100, 0.01, 60510.1}, {100, 0.015, 70971.5}, {100, 0.02, 
   90358.1}, {100, 0.025, 107710}, {100, 0.03, 155191}, {100, 0.035, 
   176332}, {100, 0.04, 268286}, {100, 0.045, 387221}, {100, 0.05, 
   446528}, {100, 0.055, 616056}, {100, 0.06, 840413}, {100, 0.065, 
   1.37393*10^6}, {100, 0.07, 1.36754*10^6}, {100, 0.075, 
   2.77176*10^6}, {100, 0.08, 2.426*10^6}, {200, 0.01, 66869.9}, {200,
    0.015, 71399.5}, {200, 0.02, 74329.3}, {200, 0.025, 
   99582.5}, {200, 0.03, 121926}, {200, 0.035, 166560}, {200, 0.04, 
   186512}, {200, 0.045, 207654}, {200, 0.05, 256898}, {200, 0.055, 
   398627}, {200, 0.06, 466594}, {200, 0.065, 662348}, {200, 0.07, 
   933421}, {200, 0.075, 1.11269*10^6}, {200, 0.08, 
   1.36385*10^6}, {300, 0.01, 67070.1}, {300, 0.015, 65805.3}, {300, 
   0.02, 80248.1}, {300, 0.025, 85741.4}, {300, 0.03, 96002.1}, {300, 
   0.035, 120096}, {300, 0.04, 159605}, {300, 0.045, 170339}, {300, 
   0.05, 228897}, {300, 0.055, 256947}, {300, 0.06, 345085}, {300, 
   0.065, 450238}, {300, 0.07, 700978}, {300, 0.075, 832152}, {300, 
   0.08, 1.32654*10^6}, {400, 0.01, 61246.9}, {400, 0.015, 
   66118}, {400, 0.02, 68661.2}, {400, 0.025, 73570.8}, {400, 0.03, 
   92025.9}, {400, 0.035, 109598}, {400, 0.04, 147937}, {400, 0.045, 
   161330}, {400, 0.05, 224650}, {400, 0.055, 266217}, {400, 0.06, 
   310519}, {400, 0.065, 447822}, {400, 0.07, 641469}, {400, 0.075, 
   806530}, {400, 0.08, 1.37741*10^6}, {500, 0.01, 56989.3}, {500, 
   0.015, 67928.9}, {500, 0.02, 69761.9}, {500, 0.025, 86710.9}, {500,
    0.03, 79849}, {500, 0.035, 97954.5}, {500, 0.04, 127872}, {500, 
   0.045, 139649}, {500, 0.05, 150587}, {500, 0.055, 275188}, {500, 
   0.06, 305953}, {500, 0.065, 426897}, {500, 0.07, 654867}, {500, 
   0.075, 966621}, {500, 0.08, 1.36171*10^6}, {600, 0.01, 
   66711.9}, {600, 0.015, 65131.8}, {600, 0.02, 73614.3}, {600, 0.025,
    78866}, {600, 0.03, 81276.7}, {600, 0.035, 102292}, {600, 0.04, 
   107857}, {600, 0.045, 139988}, {600, 0.05, 189010}, {600, 0.055, 
   260216}, {600, 0.06, 315841}, {600, 0.065, 440656}, {600, 0.07, 
   662428}, {600, 0.075, 985202}, {600, 0.08, 1.51782*10^6}, {700, 
   0.01, 69192.1}, {700, 0.015, 66052.4}, {700, 0.02, 72424.6}, {700, 
   0.025, 82281.8}, {700, 0.03, 86213}, {700, 0.035, 94029.4}, {700, 
   0.04, 114066}, {700, 0.045, 140307}, {700, 0.05, 182638}, {700, 
   0.055, 235287}, {700, 0.06, 330950}, {700, 0.065, 474889}, {700, 
   0.07, 735568}, {700, 0.075, 1.08146*10^6}, {700, 0.08, 
   1.66039*10^6}, {800, 0.01, 58843.3}, {800, 0.015, 64994.5}, {800, 
   0.02, 67298.5}, {800, 0.025, 74371.7}, {800, 0.03, 80555.1}, {800, 
   0.035, 99640.4}, {800, 0.04, 104818}, {800, 0.045, 143354}, {800, 
   0.05, 177583}, {800, 0.055, 245006}, {800, 0.06, 338566}, {800, 
   0.065, 499601}, {800, 0.07, 732425}, {800, 0.075, 
   1.17749*10^6}, {800, 0.08, 1.88361*10^6}, {900, 0.01, 
   63246.3}, {900, 0.015, 64967.4}, {900, 0.02, 67008.1}, {900, 0.025,
    79926.8}, {900, 0.03, 77706.3}, {900, 0.035, 96751.9}, {900, 0.04,
    123840}, {900, 0.045, 133210}, {900, 0.05, 178143}, {900, 0.055, 
   254075}, {900, 0.06, 355435}, {900, 0.065, 504921}, {900, 0.07, 
   756158}, {900, 0.075, 1.29332*10^6}, {900, 0.08, 
   2.01113*10^6}, {1000, 0.01, 61433.1}, {1000, 0.015, 
   63099.3}, {1000, 0.02, 66182.8}, {1000, 0.025, 72844.6}, {1000, 
   0.03, 85995.2}, {1000, 0.035, 103902}, {1000, 0.04, 109085}, {1000,
    0.045, 138993}, {1000, 0.05, 189084}, {1000, 0.055, 
   257315}, {1000, 0.06, 396645}, {1000, 0.065, 539882}, {1000, 0.07, 
   778581}, {1000, 0.075, 1.40995*10^6}, {1000, 0.08, 
   2.23897*10^6}, {1100, 0.01, 60104.5}, {1100, 0.015, 
   64439.1}, {1100, 0.02, 72467.6}, {1100, 0.025, 76612.4}, {1100, 
   0.03, 84767.1}, {1100, 0.035, 106206}, {1100, 0.04, 122682}, {1100,
    0.045, 152169}, {1100, 0.05, 198745}, {1100, 0.055, 
   259857}, {1100, 0.06, 388296}, {1100, 0.065, 564835}, {1100, 0.07, 
   899551}, {1100, 0.075, 1.46177*10^6}, {1100, 0.08, 
   2.31448*10^6}, {1200, 0.01, 58711.3}, {1200, 0.015, 
   62742.4}, {1200, 0.02, 64179.7}, {1200, 0.025, 73288.1}, {1200, 
   0.03, 85146.1}, {1200, 0.035, 96879.7}, {1200, 0.04, 
   127671}, {1200, 0.045, 154304}, {1200, 0.05, 201372}, {1200, 0.055,
    278887}, {1200, 0.06, 416279}, {1200, 0.065, 622232}, {1200, 0.07,
    962591}, {1200, 0.075, 1.54832*10^6}, {1200, 0.08, 
   2.50081*10^6}, {1300, 0.01, 58959.4}, {1300, 0.015, 
   59761.6}, {1300, 0.02, 69075.9}, {1300, 0.025, 70665.1}, {1300, 
   0.03, 87007.1}, {1300, 0.035, 105193}, {1300, 0.04, 124706}, {1300,
    0.045, 163178}, {1300, 0.05, 213193}, {1300, 0.055, 
   300242}, {1300, 0.06, 432419}, {1300, 0.065, 651916}, {1300, 0.07, 
   982562}, {1300, 0.075, 1.67169*10^6}, {1300, 0.08, 
   2.57347*10^6}, {1400, 0.01, 57704.8}, {1400, 0.015, 
   58191.2}, {1400, 0.02, 66720.6}, {1400, 0.025, 79106.7}, {1400, 
   0.03, 88716.8}, {1400, 0.035, 102867}, {1400, 0.04, 126105}, {1400,
    0.045, 165217}, {1400, 0.05, 222163}, {1400, 0.055, 
   316881}, {1400, 0.06, 460439}, {1400, 0.065, 660282}, {1400, 0.07, 
   1.14617*10^6}, {1400, 0.075, 1.69754*10^6}, {1400, 0.08, 
   2.6663*10^6}, {1500, 0.01, 59764.7}, {1500, 0.015, 62215.2}, {1500,
    0.02, 65577.2}, {1500, 0.025, 76682.2}, {1500, 0.03, 
   86029.3}, {1500, 0.035, 112143}, {1500, 0.04, 137974}, {1500, 
   0.045, 172846}, {1500, 0.05, 239260}, {1500, 0.055, 341533}, {1500,
    0.06, 485092}, {1500, 0.065, 753040}, {1500, 0.07, 
   1.16581*10^6}, {1500, 0.075, 1.86748*10^6}, {1500, 0.08, 
   3.00517*10^6}, {1600, 0.01, 62543.2}, {1600, 0.015, 
   64851.5}, {1600, 0.02, 65456.3}, {1600, 0.025, 78520.7}, {1600, 
   0.03, 87927.6}, {1600, 0.035, 109371}, {1600, 0.04, 137308}, {1600,
    0.045, 181338}, {1600, 0.05, 247086}, {1600, 0.055, 
   362190}, {1600, 0.06, 500233}, {1600, 0.065, 756103}, {1600, 0.07, 
   1.17895*10^6}, {1600, 0.075, 1.94942*10^6}, {1600, 0.08, 
   2.93227*10^6}, {1700, 0.01, 60449.8}, {1700, 0.015, 
   63595.8}, {1700, 0.02, 65236.4}, {1700, 0.025, 77964}, {1700, 0.03,
    92225.1}, {1700, 0.035, 112889}, {1700, 0.04, 142803}, {1700, 
   0.045, 184930}, {1700, 0.05, 269727}, {1700, 0.055, 362958}, {1700,
    0.06, 540865}, {1700, 0.065, 780493}, {1700, 0.07, 
   1.26828*10^6}, {1700, 0.075, 2.0631*10^6}, {1700, 0.08, 
   3.2993*10^6}, {1800, 0.01, 58425.4}, {1800, 0.015, 62231.2}, {1800,
    0.02, 69519.5}, {1800, 0.025, 80873.6}, {1800, 0.03, 
   98030.4}, {1800, 0.035, 115355}, {1800, 0.04, 147563}, {1800, 
   0.045, 203516}, {1800, 0.05, 268480}, {1800, 0.055, 390830}, {1800,
    0.06, 567131}, {1800, 0.065, 885360}, {1800, 0.07, 
   1.34411*10^6}, {1800, 0.075, 2.13143*10^6}, {1800, 0.08, 
   3.22582*10^6}, {1900, 0.01, 57286.1}, {1900, 0.015, 
   63730.3}, {1900, 0.02, 72297.1}, {1900, 0.025, 81728.8}, {1900, 
   0.03, 99080.2}, {1900, 0.035, 123071}, {1900, 0.04, 152708}, {1900,
    0.045, 205180}, {1900, 0.05, 273948}, {1900, 0.055, 
   403890}, {1900, 0.06, 591449}, {1900, 0.065, 917536}, {1900, 0.07, 
   1.3526*10^6}, {1900, 0.075, 2.21305*10^6}, {1900, 0.08, 
   3.38519*10^6}, {2000, 0.01, 59740.3}, {2000, 0.015, 
   65435.7}, {2000, 0.02, 73929.5}, {2000, 0.025, 90775.2}, {2000, 
   0.03, 100335}, {2000, 0.035, 124159}, {2000, 0.04, 159627}, {2000, 
   0.045, 214404}, {2000, 0.05, 300085}, {2000, 0.055, 422780}, {2000,
    0.06, 602504}, {2000, 0.065, 924957}, {2000, 0.07, 
   1.44754*10^6}, {2000, 0.075, 2.29632*10^6}, {2000, 0.08, 
   3.55013*10^6}}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Population Size, Mutation Probability, Generations}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

Comment: works fine for me in V9 but get the same problem in V10. On my way out so cannot investigate

Comment: That's really odd. I can't find the problem, but here's a workaround for the time being: `ListPlot3D[Transpose@Partition[Last /@ data, 15], DataRange -> {{100, 2000}, {0.01, 0.08}}, PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]` http://i.stack.imgur.com/mwQmc.png

Comment: `ListPointPlot3D` applied to the original data works properly, although it does not have the desired appearance.  Interestingly, setting `InterpolationOrder -> 0` in `ListPlot3D` also plots the entire range, but the output is wrong!  Evidently, `ListPlot3D` cannot handle data with such an enormous range of variation.

Comment: I think this is the familiar long-standing problem with the triangulation algorithm. [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19253/plotting-a-3d-list-causes-kernel-to-crash-if-x-and-y-axes-have-vastly-different/19330#19330) is related though the "DelaunayDomainScaling" option in my answer there doesn't work in version 10. A simple workaround would be to plot the probability as a percentage (`data[[All,2]] *= 100`), or the population in thousands.

Comment: Can you try with DataRange->{{xmin,xmax},{ymin,ymax},...}, or with DataRange -> All, respectivly?

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the comments, this problem has to do with the fact that the different axes have wildly different scales.  See the questions [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/98530/9490) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/68973/9490) for a discussion on this.

@Rahul gave a workaround that is specific to the case where the data is on a rectangular grid,

```
ListPlot3D[Transpose@Partition[Last /@ data, 15], 
 DataRange -> {{100, 2000}, {0.01, 0.08}}, PlotRange -> All, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

But we can make another workaround for the case where the data is even on an unstructured grid.  The idea is to rescale the data before plotting, and then rescale the tick marks so as to match the original data ranges using the [`CustomTicks`](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/5599/) package.

```
Needs["CustomTicks`"];
rescaleListPlot3D[data_, plotopts : OptionsPattern[ListPlot3D]] := 
 Module[{rescaleddata},
  rescaleddata = 
   Transpose[Rescale[#, MinMax@#] & /@ Transpose[data]];
  ListPlot3D[rescaleddata, 
   Ticks -> 
    Function[mm, 
      LinTicks[Sequence @@ mm, 
       TickPostTransformation -> (Rescale[#, mm, {0, 1}] &),
       TickLabelFunction -> (N@# &)]] /@ (MinMax /@ Transpose[data]), 
   plotopts]
  ]

rescaleListPlot3D[data, PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {Population Size, Mutation Probability, Generations}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

And we can make a contour and density plot version, since these also suffer from the same interpolation problems,

```
rescaleListDensityPlot[data_, 
   plotopts : OptionsPattern[ListDensityPlot]] := 
  Module[{rescaleddata},
   rescaleddata = data;
   rescaleddata[[All, ;; 2]] = 
    Transpose[
     Rescale[#, MinMax@#] & /@ Transpose[data[[All, ;; 2]]]];
   ListDensityPlot[rescaleddata, plotopts,
    FrameTicks ->
     (Function[mm,
        {LinTicks[Sequence @@ mm, 
          TickPostTransformation -> (Rescale[#, mm, {0, 1}] &),
          TickLabelFunction -> (N@# &)],
         StripTickLabels[
          LinTicks[Sequence @@ mm, 
           TickPostTransformation -> (Rescale[#, mm, {0, 1}] &),
           TickLabelFunction -> (N@# &)]]}] /@ (MinMax /@ 
         Transpose[data[[All, {2, 1}]]]))]
   ];
rescaleListContourPlot[data_, 
  plotopts : OptionsPattern[ListContourPlot]] := Module[{rescaleddata},
  rescaleddata = data;
  rescaleddata[[All, ;; 2]] = 
   Transpose[Rescale[#, MinMax@#] & /@ Transpose[data[[All, ;; 2]]]];
  ListContourPlot[rescaleddata, plotopts,
   FrameTicks ->
    (Function[mm,
       {LinTicks[Sequence @@ mm, 
         TickPostTransformation -> (Rescale[#, mm, {0, 1}] &),
         TickLabelFunction -> (N@# &)],
        StripTickLabels[
         LinTicks[Sequence @@ mm, 
          TickPostTransformation -> (Rescale[#, mm, {0, 1}] &),
          TickLabelFunction -> (N@# &)]]}] /@ (MinMax /@ 
        Transpose[data[[All, {2, 1}]]]))]
  ];
```

and compare the results of plotting with and without the rescaling.

```
Grid[{
  {ListDensityPlot[data, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All,
     PlotLegends -> Automatic],
   rescaleListDensityPlot[data, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
    PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic]},
  {ListContourPlot[data, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All,
     PlotLegends -> Automatic],
   rescaleListContourPlot[data, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
    PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
   }}]
```

[image]