# Problem plotting 3D data with wildly different scales - only when data is in the form of tuples

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I have some data and values for the variables,

```
data = Import["http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=J0WP1cqe", "Table"];

{xdat, tdat} = Get["http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=sEpBfkk2"];
```

I can plot this data, which is a 100x100 array, using the `DataRange` option

```
ListDensityPlot[data, DataRange -> {MinMax@tdat, MinMax@xdat}]
```

[image]

Now if I didn't want to bother with the `DataRange` option, and wanted to plot a list of tuples, I would make this list like

```
tuples1 = 
  Flatten[Table[{tdat[[j]], xdat[[i]], data[[i, j]]}, {i, 
     Length@xdat}, {j, Length@tdat}], 1];
ListDensityPlot @ tuples1
```

[image]

which is just awful.  It does a little better if I switch the indices, but it is still horrible,

```
tuples2 = 
  Flatten[Table[{tdat[[i]], xdat[[j]], data[[j, i]]}, {i, 
     Length@xdat}, {j, Length@tdat}], 1];
ListDensityPlot@tuples2
```

[image]

A workaround is to rescale the x coordinate,

```
tuples3 = 
  Flatten[Table[{tdat[[i]], .01 xdat[[j]], data[[j, i]]}, {i, 
     Length@xdat}, {j, Length@tdat}], 1];
ListDensityPlot@tuples3
```

[image]

but this is less than ideal.

This problem happens the same for [`ListContourPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListContourPlot.html) and [`ListPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot3D.html).  It is different than [this bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19253/plotting-a-3d-list-causes-kernel-to-crash-if-x-and-y-axes-have-vastly-different) which was supposedly fixed in version 10.  The workaround listed there, using `Method -> {"DelaunayDomainScaling" -> True}` does not work here.

I believe this to be related to, but separate from [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98145/listcontourplot-and-listcontourplot3d-use-better-interpolation-for-arrays-of-val), both of  which I believe should be reported as bugs.

I am using version 10.2 on Linux

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/68973/listcontourplot-interpolation-fails-if-x-and-y-axes-have-different-scales

Comment: ahhh, okay, I could delete it if it's just a duplicate of that one.

Comment: Another workaround would probably be to use `MapAt` to plot the `Log` of your `xdat`? I know, not the best option but at least it should work

Comment: I hope you won't delete it, since it is a different command (even if the same underlying problem).  It will help others who search the site for such a problem.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth pointing out for others that in the linked duplicate, one should substitute `tuples1` here for `data` there.